# Where can I ask about "finding a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource?"

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there a Stack Exchange site where you can ask questions that are marked as off-topic on Stack Overflow  because someone asked to *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource*?

Comment: Try [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @FallenAngel But only Software, or Web Apps

Comment: And make sure you read Software Recommendations' ground rules very carefully before you ask there: http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/455/how-to-ask-and-answer-software-recommendation-questions-aka-the-ground-rules

Comment: related: [Is there a less restrictive Stack Exchange site specially suited for not too specific questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252777/is-there-a-less-restrictive-stack-exchange-site-specially-suited-for-not-too-spe)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a Stack Overflow specific questions and should be asked on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @double-beep It was migrated from meta.se. And it is specific to Stack Overflow, since it asks about questions asked on SO that are marked as off-topic. Not about questions closed as off-topic on [worldbuilding.se] or any of the other sites, where using [softwarerecs.se] is *not* appropriate, and not a good answer to the question.

Comment: You could try asking on the chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Didn't StackOverflow used to allow questions looking for tools? I mean, not subjective questions asking "which is the best tool?" but quite objective questions like "does such a tool exist?" My problem with asking on Software Recommendations is that the StackOverflow community isn't there... it's here. So I don't trust that I will get as good of a response, if one at all. Granted, I haven't tried it yet so hopefully I'm quite mistaken... but that's just been my experience with other sorts of questions that get pushed to other sites.

Comment: @BVernon you can always ask how to do something in your Language, if there is a tool, people on SO will probably tell you, if not you will get other useful answers, unless no one answers, that also may happen.

Comment: @jcubic So as an example, the other day I wanted a gui for npm/yarn. At the time I didn't know Software Recommendations existed, but to be honest I probably would have asked here first anyway because I KNOW the people that potentially have the answer to my question are here... and I want to know the answer w/in 24 hours if possible... not next week. I also couldn't care less about being down voted because chances are I get my answer and it just costs me some rep on the site (or, in other words, nothing). Not trying to be obnoxious, but it just is what it is.

Comment: @BVernon Check this question [Communication between tabs or windows](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28230845/387194) the same would be how to send message between open tabs, it don't ask the question about tool but there are answers (like mine) that show the tool. You can ask questions like this and there will be no problems if library exists for that you will probably get answer with the link, if no you will get short answer with the code that show how to do that manually, without any tool, which if it's simple, should be fine.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Most recommendation questions are poorly specified magnets for spam and [bikeshedding](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31253/the-bikeshed-problem-and-stack-exchange), so we don't accept questions of this type on *any* Stack Exchange site.  If you're just looking for basic advice, there are much better resources available like Google and Amazon Reviews.

[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) has very specific requirements for their questions.  Questions that meet those requirements would have been on-topic on Stack Overflow a couple of years ago.  Today they are categorically off-topic, even if they are well-written.

Comment: Something tells me "Amazon Reviews" isn't going to find me a good cross platform unit testing framework. And Google leads me back to a closed SO question (LOL!). "Software Recommendations" looks too general. Why not try to improve SO's resistance to spam rather than have these draconian rules?

Comment: You can't filter out the bikeshedding.  Moderating these kinds of posts consumes a disproportionate amount of time and takes the focus away from the primary goal of the site, which is to solve programming problems.

Comment: Never even know Software Recommendations existed!

Comment: Part of me thinks we should offer Software Recs as an alternative in the close reason, like we do with Super User -- but then [we probably shouldn't refer people to Super User](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277872/remove-the-mention-of-super-user-from-the-standard-off-topic-close-reasons) either.

Comment: Right: what if you know you want a library (no sense in re-inventing the wheel) but you either find a plethora of them without knowing which will fit the bill, or you have no idea where to start looking? This is not only a programming question, it's an exceedingly important one to, as @robert puts it, solve a programming problem. Such questions swiftly get down-voted by the Downvote Brigade, even if the person posing the question (such as me) is not in fact "looking for opinion" but relevant experience.

Comment: @retorquere: The need is definitely there, I agree. However, from my experience when evaluating database systems for the project at my current company, it's usually the case that the asker does not provide enough information, and the answerer only knows about one particular product, and in some cases, the answerer only hears about the product without actually trying out themselves. If the use case is too specific, the question is only useful to the OP. If the use case is too broad, it becomes a list of products regardless of relevancy.

Comment: It is absurd that there is no place, no tag, no anything where such questions can be asked.

Comment: @Jonah: What do you mean?  http://slant.co happily accepts such questions, and I daresay they get good results, because their platform adequately supports these types of questions.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Did you honestly not understand that I was referring to the SE network, which not only adequately supports these questions, but would be the best place on the internet to ask them, as the innumerable, highly upvoted but closed as off-topic tool questions attest.

Comment: @Jonah: That's not a representative sampling.  For every question like that which becomes productive, there are 10 other questions just like it that you never see (because we get rid of them) that are just magnets for crap.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, Okay, I can buy that.  I still believe there would be some system that would allow the signal and filter the noise.  Just off the top of my head, only allow people with rep of 2000+ or something to ask those types of questions.  The point is, there is a class of *very* valuable information which *is* opinion based.  That is, I want to see what high rep people are saying is the best tool for doing X, and see which one gets upvoted the most, and *then* make my own decision, even if there are 2 or more competing answers.

Comment: @Jonah: Unfortunately upvotes are not a good guide for these kinds of questions.  The nature of these questions makes upvoting a proxy for how popular the question is from a "water cooler" perspective, not how reliable or accurate the answers are.  See also [The Bikeshed Effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parkinson%27s_law_of_triviality).

Comment: @RobertHarvey, water cooler popularity is often *very* valuable information.  "Value" is not equivalent to "has an unambiguously correct answer" -- that conflation is the single biggest problem with meta and moderation on SO imo.  Your claim that upvotes are not a good guide plainly contradicts my daily experience finding answers and advice on SO closed questions.  The highest upvoted answer is certainly not always the best one, but the combination of upvotes, comments, and my own judgement makes extracting good information from "opinion based" questions trivial.

Comment: @Jonah: Well, it's a tough sell.  You're going to have to convince a lot of people that there's a way to make these questions productive (i.e. allow the ones that are likely to produce a positive result to remain open) without letting the ill-advised ones to run off the rails.  The problem right now is that there's no easy/simple way to distinguish between the two.

Comment: @Jonah: You have to remember that one reason the experts are all here in the first place (and not on, say, Yahoo Answers) is that we've taken great pains to improve the signal to noise ratio, by doing things such as closing subjective questions, questions that are unclear, questions that are too broad, etc.  Real questions have answers, not polls, opinion pieces or lengthy tutorials.

Comment: Yes, a very tough sell, but mainly because of the current moderation culture, not because it couldn't work.  I agree it's tough for the reasons you pointed out, and the success of the existing system.  I think you'd need to contain opinion questions by tag, restrict their asking by priveledge, and have a different set of (albeit looser) rules governing their closing.  Basically, as long as the answers are thoughtful, evidence based, and not argumentative, they could remain open.  Getting meta approval would be a *massive* undertaking, and would need to be led by well-respected meta members.

Comment: Also, regarding your point about the current signal to noise ratio, it would be interesting to do an analysis of page views and upvotes of closed questions.  My guess is that they would amount to a significant proportion of overall views and upvotes, and thus represent a meaningful part of SO's signal.

Comment: @Jonah: You should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200144

Comment: Interesting read, but I'm still not convinced it couldn't work with additional constraints -- restricting by high rep points should eliminate most of the problems that answer cites in the experiment -- silly jokes, water cooler nonsense, etc.  Basically, I think it would work if the people involved were reasonable, respectful, and at least  somewhat knowledgeable... which sums up the majority of high rep posters in my experience.

Comment: @jonah: So your solution is to only allow high-rep users to participate in poll and big list questions?  Only the low rep users are interested in such questions anyway.

Comment: I'm not sure what big list questions are, but I'd like to be able to ask stuff like (recent example of the top of my head): "I'm trying to write unit tests for queries written for a sqlserver db, and i'm on a mac.  I'd like to test locally, without installing parallels.  is there a good tool like sqlite but which accepts sqlserver flavor SQL?  if not, any other ideas?"  I'd also like to be able to ask what is the best framework or tool in language X for doing Y.  Again, I don't care that there's not a "right" answer.  I want to hear the opinions of other experienced devs.

Comment: @Jonah: Right.  Tool recommendation questions, a subset of Big List.  There are approximately [46,800 pages of users](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=46710&tab=reputation&filter=all) having a rep greater than 1.  Of those, roughly [234 pages](http://stackoverflow.com/users?page=234&tab=reputation&filter=all#) of those users are above 10K reputation (what I would consider enough reputation for folks to have been around long enough to understand why Big List questions are problematic).

Comment: @Jonah: So under your rule, roughly 1/2 of 1 percent of all users with more than 1 reputation would qualify to participate in these questions.

Comment: I'd be fine with that.  Obviously I'd prefer 5K for selfish reasons (since I'm already there), but would be thrilled with a special rule for 10K users to be allowed to ask such questions.  Or even making it a privilege of full 20K trusted users.  It would be so valuable to be able to ask those questions that I'd be motivated to increase rep faster, too.

Comment: @Jonah: Who would answer them?

Comment: Other high rep users.  Ask and answer cutoffs wouldn't have to be the same, but both would have to be at least 2K I'd say.

Comment: @Jonah: Why don't you propose it as a feature request?  I'd like to see what the community thinks.

Comment: Maybe I will, but I fear with my low meta rep, I'd be fighting a tidal wave with a sword.  I also suspect there's a selection bias by which the type of high rep users who'd favor it are not the high rep users involved in meta.  But I should try anyway...

Comment: @Jonah in general it is best to support egalitarian solutions . I am also against the current policy but it seems that what is being suggested here is not the way to go. At any rate did you ever ask the question?

Comment: not yet, it would take me an hour or more to prepare the question the way I would want to with supporting evidence, stats, etc so I haven't had time yet

Comment: TL;DR; I would be glad to have ANY opinionated answers for my question!!! This my question got banned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38534450/embedded-string-building-library. I don't know ANY PLACE ON EARTH where I can ask about C library for embedded development and get help like on stackoverlow.

Comment: Please add  Sotfware Recommendations   to the 'closed off topic' for recomendation questions:     the questions are being asked _because_ people can't find where they should be asking:   you'll have fewer of them in SO if people find out where they _should_ be asking them.  e.g. I've seen a fair few closed and open recommendation questions over the last 4 years, but no reference to softwarerecs.

Comment: I disagree. Librarys and components are not "ready-to-use" and the site states as a requirement. Further, you get component answers all the time on SO. The only thing in question here is the format of the question.

Answer (score 14):

As [Robert Harvey points out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource/251135#251135), [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is the right place to go when you have a specific requirement and need to ask if a library exists that fits those requirements.

These types of questions are indeed off-topic on Stack Overflow.  They used to be permitted (and you may find some very old ones still hanging around), but the community learned pretty quickly that these types of questions have several problems

1. The questions are usually horribly vague and unspecific
2. They attract spam answers.
3. And even when it isn't truly spam, they attract horrible link only answers that say nothing more than "try out my awesome library here".
4. They attract duplicate answers.  How many times do you need to see someone recommend the same exact library?
5. They attract very opinionated answers and very opinionated voting, because "best" is always subjective.
6. They age horribly. New libraries come, old ones go.  They change names.  URL's change.  Links break.  What was awesome 3 years ago is now nothing more than a phishing attack.

In short, straight recommendation questions are a moderation nightmare for the community.  They require more maintenance than the value they provide, so the community decided that these questions should be off-topic.

---

All this being said, it is still possible to get a library recommendation on Stack Overflow.  But by focusing on the library, you are approaching the situation completely backwards.

Stack Overflow is not about "finding things", it is about solving problems. So your question should focus on your problem.  When you are looking for a library, more often than not, you have a specific problem you trying to solve.  Ask about **that** problem (be sure to include all of the relevant details, especially an MCVE if you have existing code).  You may get an answer that recommends a library that solves your problem, or you may find someone provides an answer with a creative way to solve the problem without the external library.

Comment: I disagree.  Librarys and components are not "ready-to-use" and the site states as a requirement.  Further, you get component answers all the time on SO.  The only thing in question here is the format of the question.

Comment: @b_levitt what specifically do you disagree with?  Given you left the same comment under Robert's answer, I assume you disagree with SoftwareRec's as being a possible resource?

Comment: @b_levitt from SoftwareRec's own meta: https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8/is-it-alright-to-ask-for-programming-tools  Granted it is older from during their Private Beta. but it is still open without any edits or disagreeing post.  So they want these questions.

Answer (score -3):

There are several Stack Exchange sites with a [reference-request](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Breference-request%5D) tag for questions about off-site books or articles. As far as I know, Stack Overflow does not have an equivalent tag for this purpose.

Comment: Note that the existence of a tag on a site does not mean that the question is on-topic on the site. Stack Overflow has a number of tags where the subject of the tag is off-topic (e.g., [tag:project-management], [tag:scrum],...).

Comment: math.stackexchange.com [appears to allow book recommendation questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21514/is-it-appropriate-to-ask-for-references-and-book-recommendations), unlike Stack Overflow.

Answer (score -10):

The answer is stack overflow.  We don't need a separate site and even the closed answers of this variety come up as top answers on search engines.

I've been following this a while and frankly I'm quite tired of resistance to this but continue trying because when I search a closed stack overflow is the answer that comes up.

All of the arguments against allowing such questions lack teeth.

- *Subject to spam* - half of the questions on SO already have a chance of later getting a "now theres a library for this".  Even in that case we have the voting mechanism to manage this.
- *bikeshedding* - do we REALLY believe there won't be enough people on the Internet to answer the tough questions if we allow component answers?  Are there people that will insist on writing "pure" code answers even when a library exists?
- *Time sensitivity* - the results will be stale.  Again, many/most questions already have that problem.  And again voting mechanism should take care of it.
- *Because there are other sites for that -* this is circular logic.  There are other sites for that because of the very rules we are trying to change. And of course when is the last time "Software Recommendations" showed up in the search engine results?  At the time of this there are 100 upvotes on this question - it is clear that people are not finding these alternate sites.
- *You could just edit the question* - Ha just kidding, this isn't presented as an option, it's just closed.  However, I mentioned it because I used to think at least it could be an olive branch.  But I've changed my mind.  First, because you have the very strict people come out and say that it changes the intent of the question.  I completely disagree with that since nobody is going to complain if you give them a couple of lines of native code that DOESN'T need a component.

  More importantly though, it reduces the effectiveness of stackoverflow...part of the power here is that people ask for the same thing in different ways.  Changing the question might make it harder for people that are looking for the same thing asked in the same way they would ask.

Most of the above arguments against what you are asking for are hypothetical and seem to make logical sense.  But there is no proof offered.  On the other hand, these questions seemed to by highly trafficked and up voted which attests to their usefulness.  Frankly, if this is so much against SO policy, the questions should just be deleted so they 404, but I guess we're not SO much against this where we'd risk a traffic drop.

**The Jeff Problem**

I've realized this really just **comes down to a misapplication of the [original Atwood article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**. People applying it are not recognizing how the nuances and abstract nature of programming make it a different case than cameras and graphics cards.  I'm not saying Jeff was wrong.  I'm saying the people that are taking an article written in the context of "superuser.com" with all hardware examples, are doing a disservice to stackoverflow.com by insisting programming components are the same thing.

This is a misapplication for a number of reasons:

**There's nothing abstract in the camera example**

If somebody asked "I need to capture a highly accurate image of a scene in a very low amount of time, would anybody balk if somebody said you need a need a "Kodak"?  And before you say yeah, but that's a brand name, [what if it's 1889?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_the_camera#Kodak_and_the_birth_of_film)  There's a time lag between when something goes from abstract to common concept.  Just because we can take for granted that everybody knows what generalized component concept of "camera", does not mean we have the same thing in programming yet.

**He asks a *specific* question about cameras.  But in the case of programming libraries, we're either asking a general question, or we are asking a specific question with context.**

For example, when somebody asks "what component can i use to dynamically create a pdf", they are really saying "how do I write a excel from this data I have", the fact that they had the notion that the answer is likely an existing library and phrased it as "what component" does NOT make it a shopping question, but instead simply shows a very basic understanding of programming.

**This misapplication is dated**

In an age of EVERYTHING being modular in a nuget or npm, "component" as universal as an "if" statement, even what would once have been considered "native" libraries.

**Rewriting "component" questions does not change the answers"

In atwoods example of "which camera should I buy for low light photography", his rewrite of the question "which features should i look for for low light photography" will result in DIFFERENT answers.

However, in the case for programming components, if somebody says "how do I write data to a excel file", they are still likely to get the same references to components.  So the guidance here should be to simply suggesting a rephrase of the question rather than closing it.

**Asking what we should learn is EXTREMELY subjective, especially in programing**

Jeff states: "Thus, when it comes to shopping questions, don’t ask us what you should buy — ask us what you need to learn to tell what you should buy"

I think this ok when a concept is well established.  Cameras might be a good example.  A question like asp.net vs jsp is well established as dynamic web technologies. But what exactly is the conversion for most component questions?  In the case of writing an excel file, do I really need to learn the openXml standard?  In the case of a reading a web response, do I really need to learn the whole tcp/ip protocol?

**Dated answers are handled by the voting mechanism**
Atwood states that specific answers are only valid for a year.  This decidedly NOT true for many component answers.  Even if it was, the voting mechanism will take care of that for us, buy letting old answers sink over time.

**Follow up questions don't really apply**
Jeff gives the following questions that would need to be asked in a true shopping question, but I can answer them all right now for all component questions.  As further evidence, I challenge anybody to find any of these questions in the comments on ANY question in stack overflow:
    What is your budget?
First off, have you really worked with so many of these components that you can give me multiple answers?  In any case, I'll take the cheapest one.

```
Where do you live?
```

Cyberspace.

```
What are your preferences?
```

See tags.

```
Which alternatives will you consider?
```

Working code.

```
When do you want to buy?
```

Yesterday, I'm already behind deadline.

Other discussions along these lines (including my own):

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/192097/230493

[How can I encourage Stack Overflow to rein in the 'subjective' vigilantes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/167516/how-can-i-encourage-stack-overflow-to-rein-in-the-subjective-vigilantes/192097#192097)

[Is it time for SO to reconsider its policy toward library-oriented questions to stay relevant with new trends in programming languages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369946/is-it-time-for-so-to-reconsider-its-policy-toward-library-oriented-questions-to)

Comment: Sorry, this misses the mark pretty much across the board. Stack Overflow is for programming questions. If you want hardware, software, tool, or library recommendations, there are sites for those.

Comment: Yet the debate rages on with closed and subjective questions on SO with no real supported reason of why they can't be there.  When is the last time a Software Recommendations link came up the the search results.  We are segmenting out these questions for no real reason.

My assersion is that "how do I x" will yield almost the exact same answers as "what component should I use to do x and will you post an example".

Answer (score -19):

I think if the reason for not allowing this type of question is that it will attract spam answers, the rejection criterion in the site guidelines needs to be changed slightly, so that rather than;

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam

it should actually read

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow which are liable to attract opinionated answers and spam

I came to this topic after posting the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35624387/any-tools-method-to-list-all-command-ids-in-a-mfc-ribbon-xml-file) and while it falls of the current rule, I don't believe it is not the type of question that would attract spam.  At a guess, many resources being sought here will often be pretty obscure and either non-existent or hard to find elsewhere.  It is also worth remembering that each visit by experienced people to this site that yields negative results and feedback is prone to turn them away from the site.  To borrow Robert's analogy above, I think the current rule kills more signal than noise.

Comment: Spam is only one reason and not the most important one as far as I know. Its more the part that there will be no definitive answer, only a mountain of personal opinions as a response to it.

Comment: Spam seems to be the main reason given in response to this issue from what I can see.  Very many questions have multiple good answers rather than a single definitive right answer.  Personally, I visit SO much less frequently these days for the simple reason I find it a very negative environment.  I don't think I'm alone in that respect.

Comment: Yes, multiple good factual answers, still not personal opinions.

Comment: @Gimby, so for a question such as 'where can I find a high performance open source C++ computational geometry library' there are clearly multiple correct answers which are not opinion based.  Yet the question is not allowed on SO, even though it has many answers that would provide value to many programmers.  Opinion only comes into play when the question uses an adjective such as good or best, i.e. which is the best library for x,y,z.

Comment: What has value is also an opinion. Me personally I use search engines to search for something, I don't degrade stack overflow to a bookmarking service - bookmarks which are likely to rot away.

Comment: @Gimby, I'd have thought what has value in SO is defined by the voting system. as defined by the opinions of the audience to a question.  Using a search engine for programming related information is very likely to return you to StackOverflow, see comments to this question for example; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/205529/passing-variable-number-of-arguments-around/205584#205584  It would appear bookmarking is encouraged within SE, otherwise why allow favouriting of questions?

Comment: @ShaneMacLaughlin: I came to the idea that the right place to put such reference content could often be tag wiki. I'm not exactly sure it would apply to the linked question, but to find ressources to learn a technology it's probably the right place.

Comment: The obvious problems with allowing recommendation questions are spam (*I'll advertise my product everywhere*), long discussions (and arguments), links that expire, and products or projects that disappear. Who is responsible for maintaining every link, removing the obvious spam, moderating the arguments and discussions, and removing answers that are no longer valid? And what happens when Product A is highly upvoted as a recommendation today, but in six months Product Z comes out with vastly better performance and a greater feature list?

Comment: @Ken, if this was true, why does it work on the software recommendations site linked in the first comment?  Most technical information has a temporal aspect, in that it may be superseded and its value diminish over time.  This is also the case for any SO answer.

Comment: "tend to" and "liable to" are synonymous phrases. There's no effective difference here.

Comment: @TylerH, similar but not the same.  'Tend to' means inclined to or likely to (do something), 'liable to' means being in a position to (do something) but not necessarily inclined to do it.  From Merriam-Webster   "Liable : being in a position to incur —used with to", "Tend: to exhibit an inclination or tendency".  In my opinion, language needs to be precise here.

Comment: @SmacL they both mean "likely to do something". There's no effective difference, like I said. If you want to be so careful with language, then we should be suggesting words that have more distance between their meaning.