# Where can I get a recommendation for online presentation software?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question, but I don't know where I can ask it. Is there a Stack Exchange site where this question would be on-topic?

> Is there an online presentation software that can produce rich, powerpoint caliber presentation in browser, right in your webpage. This is probably worded terribly. I have an education website, and I would like my users to be able to come to my website, and answer a question with a rich presentation. I would like them to be able to create the presentation on my website, without having to leave to go to another one. Is there anything out there with this capability?

Comment: http://prezi.com

Comment: @CodyGray Are you positive? I could embed their software within my website, and have my users create the presentation right on my webpage?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Comment: I doubt you can embed it. But it does produce rich presentations right in the browser. I can't see why you need to embed it. Presentations are only useful if you're *presenting* them.

Comment: @CodyGray Well we want users to be able to use presentations to answer other users questions. Additionally we want others to be able to view those presentations when they have the same question in future cases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Software Recommendations beta](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) stackexchange.