# Is there any Stack Exchange site where this question would be suitable?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have the following question:

> I would like to build a website (possibly Drupal based) for displaying
>   geneological data. The UI should include a family tree that supports
>   two parents for each node and multiple interconnections between
>   different branches. I would like to use SVG or HTML for displaying my
>   family tree and was considering eg. [**D3.js**](http://d3js.org/), [**jsPlumb**](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/)
>   or [**GoJS**](http://gojs.net/) as a library to take care of the heavy lifting.

As I can't find any demos for either of these libraries matching my basic requirements, I figured I should ask for advice on Stack Overflow and posted the following question: [**How to display a family tree structure with both parents and multiple interconnections using SVG or HTML?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207607/how-to-display-a-family-tree-structure-with-both-parents-and-multiple-interconne?noredirect=1#comment50419764_31207607) I had barely posted the question or someone marked that the question was considered off-topic. I was told the same when I posted this
question on *[User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/tour)*.

I'm confused. This kind of problem is exactly the kind of problem I typically end up solving by reading answers on Stack Overflow. I struggle understanding (1) what makes my question so different from those questions that are not considered off-topic, (2) if there's a way I could rephrase my question so it would not be considered off-topic or (3) if there's another board on Stack Exchange where I can ask my question and expect a helpful response.

Who can help me out here? I don't know where else to turn to besides Stack Overflow, and I could really use some feedback on what would be a good technical approach to tackle my requirements.

---

Below is the content of question, just in case it ends up deleted or you don't feel like clicking through.

> I'm looking for a flexible way to display the output of the [**GEDCOM
>   data model**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GEDCOM)) or [**Gramps data
>   model**](http://bettergedcom.wikispaces.com/GRAMPS+Data+Model), which are the most common data models for geneology. Both
>   data models support family trees that include both biological parents
>   and multiple interconnections between different branches of an
>   ancestor tree.
>       One example of multilple interconnections would be a case where two sisters of one nuclear family marry two brothers of another
>   nuclear family. This is the case for a distant relative of mine,
>   sometime in the 17th century, as you can see in the screenshots (of my
>   family tree in [MyHeritage.com](http://www.myheritage.com/)) below.
>
> From the brothers' perspective: [image: Brothers]
>
> From the sisters' perspective: [image: Sisters]
>
> A more complicated example would be when a greatgrandmother of a man
>   is the mother-in-law of the grandmother of his wife (or her sister).
>   Something like that too occurs among my 18th century ancestors, but
>   it's a bit more difficult to provide a suitable screenshot.
>
> While I know this can be done with Canvas, I prefer a solution that
>   uses either SVG or HTML for display. Are there any JS libraries that
>   support such multiple interconnections between different branches of
>   the same tree out of the box? Or do you know any examples for eg.
>   [**D3.js**](http://d3js.org/), [**jsPlumb**](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/) or [**GoJS**](http://gojs.net/) that supports both
>   (1) dual parent linkage and (2) multiple interconnections out of the
>   box? And if not, what approach would you recommend?

Comment: If you can follow [these guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information), you can try your luck on [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @ryanyuyu : I'm not sure how I can be more specific. What information appears to be missing in your opinion? Also, I'm not sure how "software recommendations" applies, as I'm not asking for anyone to recommend any software but merely look for a solid way to implement certain functional specs.

Comment: It's not about missing information. This is either a library recommendation question, which is off topic, or it's going to be way too broad and/or opinion based. It's simply not the kind of question Stack Overflow is meant to handle.

Comment: @ChrisHayes So why is my question considered off topic, but not eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17653327/family-tree-visualization-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454316/family-tree-design-suggestions?lq=1, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8308516/multigraphs-with-javascript? I really don't get why any of those are considered more suitable for StackOverflow than mine... nor how I should modify my question for it to be considered suitable! :-(

Comment: @JohnSleger the questions are 2 years old, 5 years old, and 4 years old. The rules changed :)

Comment: @JohnSlegers for it to be on topic for Stack, you would need to pic one library (if you can find one, I don't know enough about the topic to help you here), and THEN say "hey, using this library, I get this error when trying to do that".

Comment: @Practice I guess the rules made far more sense in the past than they do today, as IMO many of the most useful answers on StackOverflow have been answers to questions like those. Anyway, is there a way I can change my question so it is not considered off-topic? Is there anything I could add or remove for it to be considered a suitable question?

Comment: @JohnSlegers until you pick a library, I don't think so unfortunately.  The problem with these questions is that they tend to attract a LOT of opinions (my library is better than yours), a lot of link only answers (tend to get deprecated), and they tend to end up in flame war comments. All in all, they are a bad fit for the Q&A format Stack decided to take.

Comment: [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251135/839601)

Comment: @Patrice : So if I want to figure out which library is the best approach for my problem, should I ask the same question 4 times, once for each library? That seems quite redudant to me. Note that I'm not asking for any personal preference but for eg. a library or code example that is the closest match for my specs. A JSFiddle would be fine as well, as long as I get a better idea of which library to pick, really...

Comment: @JohnSlegers I imagine none of those were closed because closing is a human process and sometimes questions get missed. All the ones that *did* get closed were automatically deleted after some time, so you're only going to get a one-sided view of things by looking at old questions.

Comment: @JohnSlegers If you have 4 libraries, then you post a very specific question asking for differences between them (OBJECTIVE differences, mind you), and you phrase it... honestly I don't exactly know how you'd phrase it :S. As for your original question, you may not be asking for a personal preference, but that's what your question will attract anyway

Comment: Regarding "if I want to figure out which library is the best approach", the only answer is "don't use Stack Overflow". We aren't here to solve every programming-related issue in existence. This is one of the ones that falls outside of the site's scope.

Comment: @ChrisHayes "We aren't here to solve every programming-related issue in existence" --> I always thought that was exactly what StackOverflow was for. I guess I was wrong. Do you agree with ryanyuyu and gnat that I should give "Software Recommendations" a try? And should I repost the exact same question or should I reformulate it for it to be suitable for that board?

Comment: I don't know anything about Software Recommendations. Meta Stack Exchange has a [site-recommendation tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/site-recommendation) designed for questions like this ("where can I post this question"). If you don't get a satisfactory answer here, you might have luck with a larger cross-section of users from Meta SE. However, the ultimate answer could very well be "there is no appropriate place for this on Stack Exchange".

Comment: The problem I see with your question isn't that you're asking for recommendations of libraries (although that is off-topic here), but rather that you're asking *too early*. You don't seem to have actually tried doing anything. Stack Overflow is for when you have tried doing a few things and hit a specific problem or limitation, like "I did X but it only rendered the foos. I want the bars too, so I tried Y but got Z instead"

Comment: @Dave : So far, I've focused on the data model. So far, I've narrowed it down to two options. Now, I'm looking for a good way to visualize it. My preference goes to D3 or JsPlumb, but I'm not sure yet which library is most suitable for my specific requirements. The purpose of my question was to figure out which library is most suitable, why it is most suitable and hopefully get some demo code to get started. Most of my favorite answers of StackOverflow are that kind of answers, so I expected my question to be the perfect format for StackOverflow!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, I don't believe that any site is suitable.

Let's take your question and boil it down to its essence.

Here's the original form:

> I would like to build a website (possibly Drupal based) for displaying
>   geneological data. The UI should include a family tree that supports
>   two parents for each node and multiple interconnections between
>   different branches. I would like to use SVG or HTML for displaying my
>   family tree and was considering eg. D3.js, jsPlumb or GoJS as a
>   library to take care of the heavy lifting.

Here's the form I interpret after some distilling:

> I would like to build a website.  The UI should include some nifty things.  I would like to use some technologies and JavaScript frameworks to handle the heavy lifting.

I don't really mean to be crass, but there's **a lot** to encompass on building a website of *any* kind.  Not just that, but you mention a lot of frameworks here; some of which may be of use to your particular task, and others may not be.

You're also confusing SVG and HTML - do you mean HTML5's `<canvas>`?

There's just **too much** here.  You're asking us how to build a website with a ton of different libraries (and it really doesn't matter what the website is about), and that's the kind of thing you'd seek out a contractor for as opposed to the Stack Exchange community.

Comment: I know how to build websites. I know how to model my data. I know how to approach most of the issues involved with the project I have in mind. I'm just not clear on what approach to take for the GUI of the family free. So to answer that, I'm asking a very specific question : what technology is the best approach to building a GUI for displaying hierarchical data that meets certain functional requirements (a family free with two parents and multiple interconnections)?

Comment: ... and for the record : I did not mean HTML5's canvas tag. In fact, I was quite specific in my question as well that I did NOT want to use canvas. I want my solution to be based on SVG+CSS, HTML+CSS or a combination of SVG+CSS and HTML+CSS. An example of an HTM+CSS only family tree would be eg. http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree

Comment: So that was my impression on reading the snippet you had there.  If I had read the actual question you were phrasing, I would have delved a bit deeper; I only went off of the snippet you had provided me.  Further, your "specific" question isn't specific at all; questions that ask "which technology should I use" vary ***widly***, even if it's a relatively simple thing you may believe you're doing.

Comment: The original question is here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207607/how-to-display-a-family-tree-structure-with-both-parents-and-multiple-interconne. I'm not sure how I could be any more specific than that. Where do you believe I've been too vague?

Comment: "Are there any JS libraries that support [requirements] out of the box? Or do you know any examples for [frameworks] that support [requirements] out of the box? And if not, what approach would you recommend?"  The first is too broad because of the requirements involved; there are likely a lot of frameworks that do this.  The second is too broad because it's directly asking for outside resources.  The last is entirely opinion based as there is more than one way to approach this in JavaScript - evidenced simplest by the number of libraries which you believe you want to use.

Comment: I don't know ANY frameworks that do this OUT OF THE BOX. D3.js is probably the framework most suitable for this, but it requires a lot of custom code to implement [requirements], which is precisely why I'm looking for alternatives. Proposing an alternative that DOES support [requirements] and could save me 100s of hours of coding is anything but opinion based!

Comment: @JohnSlegers, http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com is the place to ask for library recommendations. E.g. "Is there a library that does X?" is on-topic. Does this help?