# Ideas for proposals to help Stack Overflow create a more positive community?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

So, I'm sure that I'm not the only one that's noticed [this article](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) and [this thread from /r/programming on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3cafkp/is_stack_overflow_overrun_by_trolls/), and, truth be told, there is at least a speck of truth in the things that this person and the things that the people he quotes are saying. **The gist of it is that people think that the community of Stack Overflow is hostile and unwelcoming.**

While I definitely believe in the reputation and quality of Stack Overflow, it seems that Stack Overflow has a *meta* problem; many people are dissatisfied with its community, but in many ways, Stack Overflow itself may shape its own community because of the way its current systems work.

### What sorts of systems or mechanisms can we think of to improve the quality of our community?

Personally, I think the best option is to start converting the nature of systems from combative to cooperative. As cheesy as it might sound, this might actually greatly help the tone of Stack Overflow if this shift were to occur.

Comment: +1 for the spirit, good thoughts.  But open-ended discussions asking for ideas tend to do much worse on Meta than specific, concrete suggestions - although the likelihood of implementation for the latter is low, especially if they're about fundamental changes. There also is a *lot* of existing work on the topic, this has been the subject of many a discussion and also feature request.

Comment: Some of many, many related discussions  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181040/we-need-to-be-a-little-less-hostile http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191089/why-do-we-let-hostile-users-dictate-the-perception-of-stack-overflow http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141706/how-can-we-avoid-comments-intended-to-be-helpful-being-perceived-as-unfriendly

Comment: @Pekka웃 I think the issues deserves action, though. I do like this site, and I think a lot of people would like to see it evolve into something better if it could. **It's not a matter of how many times we've talked about it, it's what can we to do take action.**

Comment: OK, so what do you propose we do? Specifically?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I suppose I should post an answer.

Comment: *What sorts of systems or mechanisms can we think of to improve the quality of our community?* Continue what we're doing now. This community is of high quality because of our no-nonsense attitude regarding crap content. That others deem us "hostile" or "declining" is irrelevant.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi While I think many of us are attracted to the quality of SO, I don't think it's good to act without abandon for respect for how other people think we treat those that visit. People can often lose arguments based on how they're acting, even if they're completely and utterly right.

Comment: OK, post an answer - although if it's a big-time proposed change, it *may* be better off as a separate feature request, but you can always still do that

Comment: @VermillionAzure: the *vast majority* of visitors are not here to ask questions though; they already have found their answer. The majority of users that perceive Stack Overflow as hostile have asked low-quality crap questions and / or did not search properly first. And that's a real problem for this site, as it becomes harder for the *experts* (those that answer the questions) to find stuff they want to answer. If we lose those users, only then is Stack Overflow in trouble.

Comment: @VermillionAzure (are you a BlazBlue player too? :) I don't see where the problem is. We have rules, the majority of us is happy with these rules, we have a consensual system in place that allow us to change those rules if necessary, and we have a steady amount of new users. Things look good from where I'm standing.

Comment: @MartijnPieters But the problem is that the community itself is aggrivated with "low-quality" visitors. If there's a thorn in your side, why not take it out and administer first-aid instead of complaining about it?

Comment: By the way, I was underwhelmed by that Medium article. It reads essentially like a write-up of everything that comes up when Googling "Stack Overflow sucks". That doesn't mean they are wrong about everything, of course; they make painfully good points. But the article fails to acknowledge the massive challenges SO is up against, and the fact that no one else has managed to come this far. As David Robinson so aptly [commented](https://twitter.com/drob/status/618120713522802688), "That city's littering laws are too strict. I'd leave, but for some reason every other city is covered in garbage"

Comment: @Vermillion well, some would argue we *are* administering first aid by shutting those visitors out. What other first aid is there when basic knowledge is missing? We can't provide that. (Yes, I agree that SO is often to abrasive, but so far I haven't seen a sane solution to the problem)

Comment: @VermillionAzure: really, the perceived hostility is eventual impatience with newcomers for not investing the effort to get to know the format and the expectations we have of what goes and what doesn't. That's the price of popularity, the absolute number of people not understanding how the site works grows. Their percentage is pretty stable,  I think; e.g. the number of people that do understand also grows, and *they don't complain loudly*.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi awh sure have a nice view, Its raining all day where I am

Comment: @VermillionAzure: there has been a great deal of work invested in stemming the tide of low-quality content coming in. That also means that people that try to inject the low-quality crap will continue to be frustrated with Stack Overflow for now being accepting of that crap.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The answer is simply to make it less hard to invest time into Stack Overflow. If people had a better "learning curve" for being a good user on SO, things would be easier. I myself have had a hard time with SO in the beginning, but I stuck it out. Not everyone has the patience to cater to the website when the website itself makes it relatively hard to adapt to.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: what makes it 'hard' is bringing assumptions about what the site does or how it works. Can you go and reread all the info provided to a new user? Open an incognito window, create a new account, and read everything provided when you do that. Can you now tell us how that information is lacking now that you know how the site works and how you struggled? Then come back and provide *that* information to us. Because I don't think you quite realise how much help is *already there*. Take into account that many people have short attention spans and burning question they want answered.

Comment: Stack Overflow exists to provide answers, not tutoring. People coming here expecting to find some sorts of free (as in beer) substitute for a programming course will be disappointed. C'est la vie.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Then perhaps the issue is based on a misconception on what Stack Overflow is supposed to be to people?

Comment: @VermillionAzure perhaps - but previous attempts to clarify this turned out to [appear even more hostile than the status quo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137795/why-what-stack-overflow-is-not-was-deleted)

Comment: @VermillionAzure: I think it is, yes. We do do our best to communicate what Stack Overflow is, but not everyone reads properly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters It needs to be made more clear. There are 1600+ people that upvoted that article that misunderstand or don't get that SO is not meant to be a general help website and Q&A and has a concrete threshold.

Comment: I am reopening this because the duplicate is over a year old, the mechanism of 'meta' needs to allow for things to be revisited, and since we have no way of making something old 'fresh again' without asking again, it's good to air on leaving these open. That doesn't compel you to participate in this discussion, but I'd like to leave it open for anyone that wants to.

Comment: @TimPost Might be irrelevant, but the objective question is pretty objective and just asks for ideas... I already agree with the meta question but it would be nice if people had some ideas.

Comment: Now, for my feedback (just mine) I think you could pretty much condense this into the last part of your question. The stuff going around that is basically 'people think' or 'people perceive' isn't in any way shown to be representative of how 'people' actually feel about the site. Many are isolated bad experiences stitched together like patchwork where the author ends with "And you could make a whole quilt out of these". I'm not saying we don't have room to improve, but I don't find many of them fair, some even less-than-factual, and all of them pretty much just 'angry'.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: no, there are 1600 people that thought the link should stay visible on Reddit. Perhaps they are going *look at that fool?*. Voting on reddit does not mean they agree with the statements made. How many of those actually visited Stack Overflow and read the tour?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Here's the top comment with 1000+ votes: *"I disagree - SO is not overrun by trolls, it is overrun by assholes. There's a difference.
Anyway, you're mostly OK if you
don't ask any questions.
post answers only in unpopular tags
I have over 20k rep and am still afraid to ask questions."*
Seems like 1000+ people think that SO is filled with assholes. :( It makes me feel sad and disappointed that our community is seen this way. However, I accept the nature of the site. That doesn't mean we can't make it more friendly!

Comment: @VermillionAzure: that comment is clickbait. If I posted a comment refuting it, thoughtfully, with references and evidence and stats, do you think it'll get voted up? Don't confuse *popularity* with *factual statements*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Factual statements on a subjective topic such as the nature of Stack Overflow's community don't exactly... exist, right? Of course, the popular answer can be representative of some part of people that looked at the thread/article, and from the number of comments, it seems to be the one that most people agree with the most.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: what I am saying is that you cannot use the absolute numbers there as proof for anything. We have no idea how many of those *actually used Stack Overflow* and can meaningfully say anything about how the site works.

Comment: In any community, virtual or meat, a small percentage are assholes, (we all know this from experience).  A small percentage of users and/or ex-users contribute to 'StackOverflow sucks' etc. sites.  Some might see a correlation in that, I couldn't possibly comment.

Comment: This question perfectly demonstrates the single most confusing aspect of meta: its votes. The votes make the question seem controversial, but in reality the upvotes are most likely a way of saying "this discussion is worth having regardless of what I think of the proposal", and the downvotes are a way of saying "this discussion is worth having, *but* I disagree with the proposal and/or its premise".

Comment: **This question got upvoted quite a lot; however, I don't even think that the current answers answer the real question!** I clearly bolded that the question is looking for solutions to our problem, and we need real ideas! Just saying, "we need to talk about it" is not what this question is asking!

Comment: @BoltClock - My down vote is for the reasons given in the tool tip. Mainly the "vague" part. The OP shouldn't be starting with the assumption that everyone will agree that the site is unwelcoming and combative, they should explain why it's unwelcoming and combative. If they want solutions to the problem, they should point out where the problem is.

Comment: I find it ironic that any solution involving work on the part of the existing members to improve things gets downvoted. Thereby underscoring the whole point of this discussion..? Hmm...

Comment: @JasonMc92 I wholeheartedly agree.

Comment: @JasonMc92 so you're saying the existing members are just too lazy to accept what are actually great ideas? And that all the arguments brought forth against those ideas are not valid in themselves, but just there to mask the community's unwillingness to do work?

Comment: @JasonMc92 I don't want to be **required** to leave a comment because i'm lazy. yeah, that's why... </sarcasm>

Comment: @Pekka웃, oh, there are valid arguments, which are discussed. I'm just saying that I'm seeing a whole lot of "nah, I don't want to do that," and not a lot of "we (not just THEY) could do THIS instead to address that problem." As the saying goes, if you're not part of the solution...

Comment: @JasonMc92 not sure how much of it is "I don't want to do that" - very often, it's going to be "I don't think there's going to be enough people willing to do that."

Comment: @Pekka웃, reading through anything suggesting changing downvotes at all, in any shadow or form, feedback is mostly "I don't want (downvotes) different because I don't." One should never *just* reject all available ideas, for whatever reason, without having any of their own for solving the obviously present problem. (That approach isn't democracy, it's Congress.)

Comment: @KevinB, Okay, so you have another reason. Given our earlier conversation about how downvotes by themselves don't help anyone improve, and contribute to the unfriendly impression the question outlines, why are you opposed?

Comment: @JasonMc92 The majority of the time i'm not voting to indicate that the user should improve their question, i'm voting to rate the quality of the question so that it will be properly sorted in search results and question listings. high quality questions that are upvoted show up higher, and low quality questions that get downvoted show up lower. If i wish to help the user improve their question, i'll do so with a comment or an edit. One action is not a direct result of the other.

Comment: The multi-choice option doesn't really improve the situation. If you wanted to make some kind of response required, it would have to be an open-ended response. Canned responses are going to be just as useless as no response at all. Simply choosing "it was unclear" or "it was wrong" or "it needs more research" is very vague and unlikely to actually convey to the OP what needs to be done to improve the post. What part is unclear? How is it wrong? What more do i need to research?

Comment: @KevinB: 1) I did suggest a freeform box at the bottom, and if you want to be MORE helpful, you can fill that out and/or leave a normal comment. 2) It's more helpful than nothing. Right now, most people view it like a YouTube downvote, and DO take it personally. No amount of propaganda will change that, especially b/c there are many people around here who DO use downvote just to be poison mean. 3) "Quality" is such a vague and subjective thing, and many believe that an otherwise good question that "the asker should JUST KNOW the answer to" is "low quality", when it isn't.

Comment: In the end, we're looking at reducing three things: A) malicious misuse (or perception thereof) of the downvote, which contributes to the problem mentioned above, B) a vague, abstract, pell-mell definition of "quality" that, given a proper meta discussion, I'm fairly sure none of us would agree fully on, C) a starting place for improving questions/answers. "Not enough research" or "Incorrect information" is still more helpful than a silent downvote, and it largely rules out the conclusion that "they downvoted b/c they hate me."

Comment: All of these arguments have already been made http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/ http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/ and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6521/ I am on the boat of followup every downvote with a comment, but, i still don't believe they should be required. Two separate systems with two separate purposes. (@VermillionAzure and a discussion like this in comments is exactly why an open-ended question like this is terrible. No one will find this discussion if they're looking for it.)

Comment: @KevinB In that case, if we were to agree that they're two separate mechanisms, we can only conclude that downvotes do more harm than good (see above), and really need to be DC'd altogether. SO is unique in its (very vague) definition of the downvote...everywhere else on the internet, downvote unanimously means "you suck".

Comment: https://blog.stackexchange.com/2009/03/the-value-of-downvoting-or-how-hacker-news-gets-it-wrong/

Comment: And now we have looped all the way back around - for that mechanism to work, we have to distinguish, lest it be a social "dislike". (Also https://twitter.com/codinghorror/status/618541104107929600)

Comment: @KevinB It's much better to formalize debate in questions rather than just say nothing and have it all be scattered around questions, or worse, on "terrible Reddit posts."

Comment: @Pekka웃 people have been complaining about how SO operates *for years*, and yet for all that complaining, no one's come up with anything better. Reminds me of that quote from Winston Churchill: "*Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time*". Replace "democracy" with "Stack Overflow", and "government" with "Q&A".

Comment: I've got a good rep (nearly 17k) on SO and I'm hesitant to ask questions for just these reasons. One mistake in my assumptions and people get hostile. Too narrow? Downvote. Can't replicate? Downvote. *And I know how the system works.* If I were a newbie I'd be *terrified* after my first experience. Sudden edits. Downvotes. Closed questions. Migrated questions. Limited rights. Yes, I've seen the poor quality questions too. I realize this is a hard problem, and I don't have a solution, but *it is a problem.* Can we discuss possible solutions without  discounting the problem?

Comment: Stack doesn't want constructive idea. Stack prefers to go through major crisis, and to destroy itself. The actual crisis is only the beginning. When someone tries to be positive, all the negativity flows back. For instance, suggesting other users to explain why they want to close a question, only attracts hatred.

Comment: downvoters should necessarily leave a comment, even an auto-comment, explaining the reason.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

I propose we read posts like [The decline of Stack Overflow](https://medium.com/@johnslegers/the-decline-of-stack-overflow-7cb69faa575d) with a critical eye and recognize that it's little more than a Google/copy/paste article designed to drive traffic to a blog.

Let's look closely at the examples illustrated in the article.

[image: How can I get rid of 'this' keyword in local functions?]

[Here's that post today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28525393/1288) after being edited extensively by the OP a few months back, then reopened and upvoted by the community. (What a bunch of *trolls*!)

Next...

[image: Fast database access from .Net]

[That post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10822/1288) was reopened nearly *six years ago* by a moderator (What a *Nazi*!). What's more, that question was closed by a single user back in August 2008, a month before the official launch of Stack Overflow. (The site was still in "beta" at the time.) The rules for closing questions changed *years* ago. This problem has been thoroughly solved for some time.

Finally...

[image: Angle between points?]

[That question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5122372/1288) was also extensively edited by the OP back in 2011. It wasn't reopened by the community until a few months ago, probably because it lacked exposure due to a missing [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag. It also got a good answer after being reopened. (Why do we *hate n00bs* so much?)

These cherry-picked examples really illustrate what kind of "reporting" this is.  It's the kind you get when you get your news from echo chamber aggregators like Hacker News and (to a lesser extent) reddit/r/programming. When people just want to complain about something, they'll go out of their way to find problems, even if they've long been fixed.

---

That's not to say that I don't think Stack Overflow has problems. I was a moderator here for six years. I've seen the worst this site has to offer. I just don't think our personal blogs and reddit comments are the place to talk about them *if we want them to be fixed*. We do that here on Meta.

Comment: With statements like "[I've been a member of many online communities, but nowhere have I experienced so much hostility and](https://twitter.com/johnslegers/status/618132938757120000) [immaturity among moderators. It seems to me the criteria for becoming a moderator are poorly chosen.](https://twitter.com/johnslegers/status/618133138645123072)", the author seems like they have a lot of anger they want to vent.

Comment: @BradLarson I hadn't seen that thread. He seems very uninterested in actually fixing any problems.

Comment: There’s actually a healthy discussion on r/programming of this post (well, for reddit it’s *surprisingly* healthy). Nevertheless, the blog post itself is purely toxic.

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm probably being unfair to r/programming by lumping it in with HN under the "echo chamber" label. I unsubscribed from it years ago when I felt like it was suffering too much from its own popularity, but it's far from the worst programing community on the web.

Comment: @BradLarson I think another clue is the author's last Meta post (from Friday): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298538/is-there-any-stackexchange-site-where-this-question-would-be-suitable, at which point this sort of looks like the results of a misspent weekend of Googling

Comment: @David Hm, I empathise with the guy at this point … I never particularly liked SO’s overly narrow focus and its zealous deletion of perfectly fine questions. This one may not technically fit SO (for entirely arbitrary reasons) but it’s not fundamentally a bad question, and there’s a way of providing good answers to it, even in SO’s format.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard: Honestly, the article alone does more than enough to show that. Of all the viral "Stack Overflow sucks" posts I have seen, the tone in this one is *by far* the most vitriolic of its kind - it makes the others seem *pleasant* in comparison. Once you've resorted to categorizing an entire community of users as trolls it means you have basically given up on that community.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I agree with your examples and the gist of your argument. Don't you think it's ironic though, that this topic here on meta has been down voted? To me, that says volumes about the SO culture. By simply asking for ideas to make things more positive, the OP is down voted. Awesome.

Comment: @williamdnapier: Absolutely one of the most frustrating and confusing aspects of meta. See the comment I just left on the question a couple of minutes prior.

Comment: @williamdnapier Read the top few comments on the question. A downvote doesn't mean "How dare you even *suggest* we improve?"

Comment: @Brad Larson: "immaturity among moderators", [eh](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126919/evaluating-the-risks-of-allowing-teen-moderators-on-the-se-network)?

Comment: Excellent post; but how does this answer the original question? This doesn't provide any ideas about how to improve the community; even if the site already works fine, I'm asking for improvements to make it better than it is right now, even if it works great.

Comment: @VermillionAzure We don't really need a separate question for ideas on how to make a more positive community. If people have suggestions on how to do that, they're *always* welcome to post those suggestions here on Meta. This is like having a separate question on SO where people can post their programming questions as answers. Since the whole premise of your question was based on a blog post, I addressed the premise instead.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Objectively, the this answer doesn't put forward an idea. I asked this question simply because of the large approval the original thread got on Reddit and I'm trying to frame the question as a response to the gripes of the blogger. Despite the tone or style of the blog, I myself think there is truth in what he is saying at least on some level. Although the discussion is nice, I'm also looking for feature ideas to "soften" the problem. Stack Overflow can be mean, but that doesn't mean that people don't want it to be nicer.

Comment: @VermillionAzure My issue isn't with the tone or style of the blog post, it's with the facts. He didn't have any to support his opinion, so he manufactured some. The fact that that got large approval on reddit indicates that a lot of people on reddit don't fundamentally understand the purpose of Stack Overflow. My suggestion for improving the community is to post suggestions here on Meta.

Comment: Two of these questions were reopened and upvoted because Jason S [mentioned them in a blog post](http://www.embeddedrelated.com/showarticle/741.php) that was picked up by both Reddit and Hacker News. The system needs a little nudge sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Ah, I was wondering what happened there. I think either of those would have gotten reopened after a Meta post.

Comment: But what do you do if your first question gets closed when it shouldn't? You can't post on Meta with 1 rep. You can't even flag for a moderator (edit: no, actually you can... if you see the button). Editing puts it in the reopen queue, but how would a newbie know that? (Is that mentioned in the close message to a new user? I don't actually know.)

Comment: @MichaelMyers I don't know either. A noob probably wouldn't know any of this, and probably shouldn't be expected to. There are a lot of other people in the community who can edit/vote/post on Meta, though. Jason S could have done that for the two examples above.

Comment: All the close messages encourage editing now, @MichaelMyers. That was a pretty major design goal a couple years back, for exactly this reason.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I re-read all the comments and the question. To your point, the question appears to have been down voted because it was open-ended and, of course, has been asked many times before. I do think moderators and high rep users influence SO culture and have shaped it over time. Personally, I try to up vote helpful answers and comments w/o snark. There is a certain tendency in human nature for the 'haves' to put the 'have nots' in 'their place'. Its a problem on every forum site. That is one reason I voted for the moderators I did this past election.

Comment: @williamdnapier That tendency goes both ways. I wasn't being snarky.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Oh, I know. I didn't mean you personally, it was just a generalization regarding SO. We're just talking.

Comment: @williamdnapier I don't see SO/Meta as a conflict between the "haves" and "have nots" as much as it is a conflict between people who have been around and know the rules, and people who haven't been and don't. Meta in particular. The reasons for downvoting can seem to change with each question, even to people experienced on SO.

Comment: Instead of answering the question, this post denies a problem exists. The fact that it has been upvoted as often as it has shows that lots of us are in denial...

Comment: @JayElston If you think the premise of the question isn't deeply flawed, you're free to post your own answer.

Comment: "the author seems like they have a lot of anger they want to vent. It's normal to be angry, when you meet scorn and disdain here. Hey, man, you didn't wash yourself, you stink. Me??? People who say that are only full of anger. Good job community, SE will only go on crisis like the current one, but you prefer to be denial, and to sabotage it.

Answer (score 32):

As always, these complaints fail to come to grips with the sheer scale of garbage on the Internet. For each reasonable person who has a bad experience here, there are thousands of creeps who show up and deposit trash.

At the scale of the entire Internet, you can't help everyone; you can't set up a system that 'trains and educates' those few who could be trained and educated while still controlling all the incoming trash. You can't even control all the people who have enough reputation to leave a snarky comment.

The experience of someone on a site like this is a two-way street in two ways. Of course, first, the new user could search, read the FAQ, etc., and likely avoid any kicks in the shins. More to the point, they could realize that posting a question in front of the entire Internet is likely to result in responses that span good, bad, and snarky (not to mention written by a dog wearing a tinfoil hat). And grow a thicker skin. That's a very low price for free help.

Luckily, fewer and fewer people need to ask a question at all, since more and more just find what they need already here.

Comment: We *could* attempt to change the culture by not tolerating unhelpful behaviors.

Comment: @tvanfosson Such as... Everyone says we have all these "unhelpful" behaviors, then never has a way to change them without affecting site quality (note that the usual "unhelpful" behaviors are often very helpful)

Comment: Some tiny number of people make snarky remarks. That's pretty much it for 'unhelpful'. Downvotes aren't 'unhelpful', they are rating the content, which is what the site needs.

Comment: ["downvotes are taken so damn personal... They are not there to insult anyone..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253230/839601)

Comment: Downvotes are not unhelpful, downvotes without trying to help the user is unhelpful. But how many here are able to understand this? This community is self-sabotaging now, but people prefer to say "everything's all right".

Answer (score 21):

In my opinion, the best way to improve the community is to disallow people to post crappy questions. It is harder and harder to find an interesting question in a pile of duplicates/garbage, and this causes knowledgeable users to contribute less.

It is not interesting to:

- answer for the 20-th time why a person has a problem with `this` in JavaScript
- debug code for a person who does not want to do any debugging and wants only a working version of his copypasted code
- read five pages of code to find a problem, just because OP did not even wanted to localize the problem
- answer questions. "I am a total noob with X, Y, and Z, but I need to develop a system which will handle millions of requests per second. What is the right approach?"

The community is already doing too much work trying to convert a [shit to a sweet](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24260177/revisions) by editing every `i try codes thet does stuff 'bunch of unformatted wall of code' and hve prblem. can y help me fast??? only java` into something more or less readable. I am not speaking here about the problem with English (not a native speaker myself), but if a person has spent less than a minute writing his question and did not even bother to look at it after posting, why are we surprised with hostility (I am actually surprised that there are people who spend their time trying to edit this).

Stack Overflow is here to help (do not be confused with `tech support`, `debug`, `teach`) with programming problems. And it is a responsibility of the help seeker to learn the rules, be polite, be as clear as possible with the problem.

Comment: This attitude is why I participate less and less as time goes by.  I *do* come here to both learn and teach (and thereby learn more and deeper).  The narrowing of SO to the mechanical "solve this particular problem" has made it much, much less interesting to me.

Comment: One the one hand, yes, we have a lot of "give me da codez" and such questions that help no one. On the other hand, many GOOD questions are blasted by some of the less-friendly SOers, simply because "the person should JUST KNOW the answer, despite the fact it is not documented anywhere in existence," or "who the #%&@# uses that platform to do that task??", or "who the @%#%&@ does that task?" Thus, if we just vaguely "don't allow posting crappy questions", we have carefully craft a system that cannot be abused. Meanwhile, no one can improve if they only see "your post sucks, go die."

Comment: (Not that you're suggestion that error message show up, but that type of response is present on MANY programmer web communities, USENET not being least among them.)

Comment: In regards to your first point, that sounds like the problem people used to have with USENET groups -- people kept asking the same questions over and over. It's my understanding that's what lead to F.A.Q.s. Maybe SO needs some sort of "Commonly Asked Questions" about a topic that point to canonical SO questions with the answers. (This might be a good project for a third party website.)

Comment: @Slapout: That are our highly-scored, often-viewed, and/or oft-linked questions.

Answer (score 13):

The term 'positive community' appears to be somewhat subjective.  In my experience of SO, other users have been almost entirely helpful and encouraging, with the culture being one of helping those who are willing to help themselves.  I don't see much scope for making that any more positive, however the exisitence of this question demonstrates that other members of the SO community do perceive there to be a problem.

In order to make further proposals for how to "help Stack Overflow create a more positive community", it is essential to have a precise, objective and unambiguous definition of the problem and some meaningful metrics that could be used to determine whether it has been solved.

Therefore, my proposal is that we need to define and quantify the problem in order to be able to determine what specific solutions could be applied and even whether it needs to be addressed at all.  To this end we would have to answer the following questions.

- What is the definition of 'positive community' and how can it be measured?
- What effect does the positivity of the community have on the ability of the site to meet its goals and how can that be measured?

In doing so, care must be taken to ensure that the metrics used are free of statistical and (if applicable) psychological bias, or that any such biases are identified and can themselves be quantified and the metrics adjusted accordingly.

Further solutions can then be analysed for their capability to address the underlying causes of the unwanted effects of the current community's positivity; implemented; piloted to determine their effectiveness and eventually rolled out once they've been shown to solve the problem.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I would say that despite the objectivity, there is indeed a group of people who have developed an aversion to SO based on its community, for whatever experiences they had.

Comment: "other users have been almost entirely helpful and encouraging, " Are you joking?

Answer (score 10):

What people, including the article writer, don't get is that Stack Overflow is a website for *serious computer science professionals*, not wannabe coders looking for easy homework help and fun conversation. This is coming from someone who was on the receiving end of some pretty nasty anti-newbie sentiment, but all that did was teach me how to behave like a professional and still take down trolls. (My speech "A Field Guide to Common Nerds" is based entirely on those experiences, and how a newbie can survive in the programming field.)

Stack Overflow isn't perfect, but it achieved its goal of having more reliable programming information than anywhere else online, shy of the documentation, in my humble opinion! Its flaws are not unique - in fact, Stack Overflow is considerably *nicer* than other similar communities, namely programming forums and Usenet, which have a considerably larger noise-to-info ratio anyhow. The community's flaws are based in the personality quirks common to the computer science industry, which [Eric S. Raymond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond) did a pretty darn good job of documenting.

That said, I do think that Stack Overflow could be made less hostile to beginners who really do want to learn and aren't just asking us to "give me da codez". Somewhere else on meta, a year or two ago, someone made the brilliant proposal of **new users having to actually complete an interactive training session before posting to Stack Overflow**, in which they learn what a good question, a good answer, and a good comment should look like. For one thing, it'd cut down on OUR work as reviewers.

As much as I hate getting downvotes, I think the mechanism is still important for flagging especially problematic questions. Without it, we're more likely to create an atmosphere that, while "friendly" to beginners, mirrors the [Eternal September](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternal_September) on Usenet, when the noise overwhelmed information because of the sudden uncontrollable influx of idiot-category newbies.

More than anything, I think the problem with downvotes is that many people on Stack Overflow misunderstand a downvote as a proverbial "dislike" button, much like on YouTube, and never bother to read the tooltip.

I honestly believe that **if downvoting REQUIRED a comment, at least an anonymous one, explaining "why" - and if the tooltip text were clearly written above that special comment box - we would get less mindless downvoting, and a more constructive environment**. The more habitually unfriendly people would actually have to come to terms with the fact that they are often downvoting just because they're arrogant, self-important twits, not because the question or answer is inherently bad. Then, the *constructive* downvotes would be able to survive, and actually provide a means for the poster to IMPROVE future questions and answers.

This downvote comment could even be multiple-choice like our flag box is now. One extra click, and still anonymous, and it would provide the information that others need to A) improve their posts, and B) recognize *why* an answer is a bad idea before they ignore the "dislikes" (so they think) and run with it.

Those steps alone would go a long way to improving the community, without losing sight of why Stack Overflow is here in the first place, or irritating the living daylights out of those of us who know what on earth we're doing.

Comment: Agreed with most of your post, but [beware that you're diving into the deep end of Meta by suggesting comments for downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/250177/require-a-comment-explaining-the-reason-for-the-first-downvote-on-a-question).

Comment: Since i can't -.5, i'll round it up(down?) to -1. interactive training session, i'm unbiased about because i don't know how many of the new users would simply do whatever they could to skip past it as fast as possible, how many would use it legitimately to learn *but then fail to apply it to their question*, or how many would actually learn from it and post a great question. Requiring downvotes to be accompanied by a comment on the other hand.... no...

Comment: Mmmm... where do the "enthusiasts" fit into your "serious computer science professionals"? Where do I fit in? "professionals and enthusiasts" it says on the tooltip at the bottom of the page. Where did you find that description of yours?

Comment: @BillWoodger, frankly, I consider "enthusiasts" to be as much a part of the group of professionals as anyone. After all, that's where I started. Serious enthusiasts make up a good portion of hacker culture (hacker, not cracker). They also fall into the same category of seriously wanting to learn and improve, not just be handed the answer on a silver platter.

Comment: I know I'm "diving into the deep end", but it IS a legitimate answer to the question. Downvote without information is just anonymous, useless criticism. Anything done online that one doesn't want attached to their name shouldn't be done anyhow, but notice that my proposal actually suggested ANONYMOUS comments. Shoot, even a multiple choice like on a flag would be more productive than what we have now.

Comment: I could care less if someone knew i was the one that downvoted them, i just don't want to have to add a comment that simply repeats the tooltip. Maybe, once a question (or answer) is downvoted, present the downvote tooltip as a note on the question to it's owner.

Comment: The problem is, A) many don't read the tooltip, and B) "not useful" doesn't say anything. Wrong info, no effort before posting, horrendous question format, suggesting a dangerous practice, just saying "I don't agree with this"...what does "not useful" mean?

Comment: So enthusiasts and people who happen never tio have attended a Computer Science session still fit in "serious computer science professionals" sufficiently for an average meta reader to understand that?

Comment: it means not useful of course. but i assume you mean *"Why"* isn't it useful, which is a valid point.

Comment: @KevinB, yes, exactly. Like I said, even a multiple choice like on our flag box. If no one wants to put in the extra effort on a downvote to provide a why, then they are essentially wanting everyone else *besides them* to put in a little extra effort to improve the community.

Comment: I focus more on question downvotes than answer downvotes, answer downvotes don't have much meaning short of improving that one answer. Question downvotes on the other hand impact how visible the question is. The tooltip for downvoting a question has far more meaning than "not useful"

Comment: @BillWoodger, yes, they do. It's a case of 'read the documentation', oftentimes. There are a ton of resources online. I don't have a degree in this. I'm almost completely self-taught, except for one C++ class I took well after I started hanging out SO.

Comment: @KevinB, well, sometimes, but it still is important to know on an answer things like "This doesn't answer the actual question," or "This method is unsound," or "This contains inaccurate information." Again, just a multiple-choice selector, with the obvious freeform "Other" option at the bottom. One extra click.

Comment: @KevinB, going back and addressing your other point - by interactive training session, I mean having to actually answer multiple-choice "what is wrong with this part of the question/comment/answer" type questions on some example posts, after reading through the basics. They can retry the training session as many times as they want, but until they get all eight or so questions right, they can't post. It can't just be ignored like our FAQ is now.

Comment: I like the interactive training idea, it's just that without more testing to see how effective it would be, i can't really vote on it. I would expect it to not be very effective, because I, even after answering 2k+ questions, still feel intimidated by asking questions because generally, when asking a question, it means you failed to research/debug, and by the time i do both of those things, i no longer have a question to ask. Knowing what is right or wrong in a question doesn't teach you how to debug and research which is the biggest problem with low quality questions.

Comment: Things are being considered, see here, meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295683/1927206, and Tim Post's answer on that.

Comment: Yes, that's a skill that has to be acquired. I'm in the same boat, and *I'm a CEO/lead dev at a software company*. Basically, the interactive training is meant to screen out A) horrible grammar, B) give me da codez, and C) this question has been answered 2.5 million times now.

Comment: @BillWoodger, thanks for the link. That'd work too, yeah.

Answer (score 10):

As a longtime reader and a more recent contributor, I see a few things that I haven't seen mentioned her (or in other similar threads).

- Except in a few new technologies, it seems like all the core (beginner) questions have already been asked and answered.  My suggested "next badge" is to ask five questions.  I've been programming for 25 years, and I can't think of any questions that are not either already asked or so narrow that nobody can answer.  It is a lot easier on the other Stack Exchange sites to ask basic questions, because they haven't been around as long.
- At the beginning of Stack Overflow, the superiority of this site compared to the competition was only really apparent to those who already had a clue, and it wasn't at the top of most search results, so beginners would go somewhere else, not here. That is no longer true.
- With increased number of visitors, there are increased demands on the number of items to be worked in the queues, which means less time to be nice to beginners.

Pointing all this out is a great way to make up excuses, but it doesn't fix the core problem. The core problem, as I see it, is that all of the Stack Exchange programming sites assume the questioner understands computer programming enough to be able to sift through various search results and understand what the answers are saying (this is true on non-programming sites as well, as it turns out).

Maybe we need to consider a Beginners Stack Overflow site. Maybe if we let people who write blogs or books (aka "educators") help out beginners for a chance to plug their own work, we can separate questions into "We need to find out the answer" and "We need to help the questioner" buckets, and send the second set to the new site, where people can be more patient to the confused.

I don't know if that it's the right solution. I'm just trying to help make things better.

Comment: The beginners will of course find this site instead of the beginners site, thus making it somewhat useless to them. How do you differentiate between a professional that never used SO and a beginner that never used SO? Who would **want** to participate in the "beginner" SO?

Comment: I guess I was thinking that we could migrate certain questions to the beginners site.  Now that I've slept on it, another way to somewhat leverage current SE technology would be to open a chat room for the OP for these questions and encourage (through reputation or other methods) people to help educate posters.  As to who would want to do this, I mentioned "educators" who had something to gain from this (book authors and bloggers who want eyeballs).  Maybe we can think about resume building certificates or something?  I'm just trying to explore possible answers here.

Comment: @GuySchalnat When I proposed an idea like this in the form of [Atomic Coding](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/20536/why-atomic-coding-is-not-stack-overflow), it was easily shot down. I don't think SO is really the place to do this.

Comment: @vermillionAzure I see.  Thanks for sharing.  I'm not giving up on the idea that we could do something better for some of our users.  I'm not exactly sure what yet, so I'm spending times in review queues and reading meta posts and SO help and thinking about things.  Eating my waffles and riding my ponies.  At some time, I may try to shape up another proposal along different lines.  We will see.

Answer (score 3):

To be specific about an issue, I think that the duplicate tag is applied too loosely. It's very discouraging to come to Stack Overflow, search for your answer, not find it, ask a question, and get it labelled duplicate even though it's not a duplicate. There are many times when it's justified (probably the majority), but quite a few where it's not. This seems like one of the canonical posts on the subject: [How should duplicate questions be handled?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10841/how-should-duplicate-questions-be-handled). This link seems to imply a much more lenient benefit-of-the-doubt policy than what is currently employed. Consider this quote:

> It depends. If a question is an exact duplicate, then go ahead and (vote to) close it. However, note that questions may be similar without being exact duplicates:

The word exact is pretty strong IMHO, suggesting that if the question is in the grey zone, it should not be closed.

Unfortunately, the current mechanism has a bit of the opposite tendency built in. 30 people with close privileges can see a question; 25 don't think it should be closed, but they don't want to answer, and 5 think it should be closed. The 5 vote to close, and it's closed. Then you need to gather people to vote to re-open which isn't easy.

I don't know what mechanism exactly would solve this. I do think though that if a question that's marked duplicate is re-opened, there should be a loss of reputation. If you lose reputation for writing a sloppy question or sloppy answer (as perceived by other people), why shouldn't you lose reputation for sloppily closing a question (as perceived by other people). Similar mechanisms should apply for other grounds for closing a question (too broad, opinion-based, etc.). This would at least give a small amount of incentive to not close incorrectly.

Comment: If something is flagged / close voted as a duplicate, a comment will be automatically created stating "Possible duplicate..." this allows you to then state your case that it is not a duplicate. It also helps to reference those questions and their answers in your question and sate why it did not solve your problem. If your question still gets closed, you can edit your question with a clear statement of why the duplicate question's answers do not answer your question, then it will go through the reopen queue where five other users will vote on whether or not to reopen the question

Comment: @TinyGiant The time between possible duplicate and closing can sometimes be minutes. This mechanism is not very transparent to a new user. In addition, what with group think, people tend to down vote and make negative comments on a question when they see that it's possibly a duplicate. Once the question is closed, many users simply won't bother again. I think it's good you point out that some mechanisms are in place, but I still feel in practice it's an issue, and a penalty for premature closing is appropriate.

Comment: I don't often see downvotes on duplicate questions unless those questions also have severe formatting / content issues. Questions that are closed are actually reopened quite often and the reopen queue is usually close to empty if not empty entirely. The fact of the matter is that this system works. It may not be a completely transparent process to new users, but it does work and if a question really is not a duplicate (not just that the user couldn't figure out how to apply the answers from the other question to their question) and it is a good question, then it will most likely be reopened...

Comment: The system is not perfect, no system is, but it works great when it works. Yes there are things that get lost along the sidelines, but for the most part it works as intended. More than anything else, the issue is with users asking questions when they don't understand the community and the guidelines.

Comment: I've seen many closed questions where I haven't felt that way, and I know many intelligent people, some with lots of SO rep and some who barely used the website, who've had similar observations. I agree that it "mostly" works as intended, but there's still plenty of unintended that could be improved.

Comment: I agree, I have spent time answering questions that get closed as duplicates that are not really duplicates.

Answer (score -5):

"They don't provide any constructive ideas!"
That's sort of like the problem with this whole site in a nutshell.
And maybe with too much of the internet, really: people can get in and attack and criticise because it is so much easier than doing something.
Then again, it's no wonder "people think that the community of Stack Overflow is hostile and unwelcoming" when so much of the discussion of this issue is itself... "hostile and unwelcoming"?

Comment: What does that add over [your previous answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/299307)?

Answer (score -8):

The fact that so many IMO good comments HERE (posted not by me) are downvoted so much actually speaks for itself. SO community is somewhat hostile and not very welcoming IMO. I know most of whoever couldn't care less, but I am going to use my freedom to post here and say that SO is basically based on the "people like us " principle. Congratulations - the rest of the internet is obviously swimming in garbage and SO is a ouh-so-not-garbage walled garden!

I realize that I am not providing any constructive solutions in this comment, but hey, so many comments HERE way more constructive than mine got shot down so fast... That I am not even trying... You get my point - I hope.

Comment: Except that comments *in the comment box* cannot be downvoted. When people abuse the answer feature by posting comments, questions, or other kinds of non-answers, the tools that we have available to deal with this is downvotes, flags, and delete votes. It is not Stack Overflow's fault that some new users cannot understand the rules and guidelines, if they even bother to read them at all. Other new users read and comprehend the documentation before using a service, thus allowing them a more seamless entry into the system.

Comment: And you downvoting a comment is not abuse? And how did you exactly disprove anything that I said in my comment? Clearly you disagree with what I am saying since I you downvoted my comment  - I imagine.

Comment: BTW I stopped caring about downvotes and trolls on SO a long long time ago. And thanks to the rules of the meta - I can comment in the meta - so I am exercising my rights. And you downvoting my comment - is your right - but do I need to explain that it is hostile? Or am I supposed to not take it personally? lol wink wink

Comment: I do disagree with your comment. I have detailed one of my counter points in my previous comment. Note that [voting is different on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta). Downvoting a comment *that is posted as an answer* is not "abuse". I also did not mean "abuse" as in physical or mental abuse, but rather as to imply that it was an improper use of the feature which is documented as being disallowed.

Comment: You're right, this is meta and this is intended to be a discussion. On main it is not intended to be a discussion, which is why comments aren't allowed to be posted as answers. Also on meta, users show agreement or disagreement with questions and answers through voting. On main, voting is used to indicate usefulness, relevance, completeness, quality, etc. but generally not to show agreement or disagreement.

Comment: Exactly my point. We disagree. Not just about whatever silly SO rules that mean rather nothing. But about what comments here are helpful or not. My opinion is that multiple helpful comments here are downvoted for no good reason. Hence - I am saying that this discussion is great - for the record. We can actually see the hostility in action. Cheers.

Comment: And what is the matter with the css shading of comments with less than -9? Makes them hard to read. And this is regardless of whether you agree or disagree with a comment...

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh I took *"The fact that so many IMO good comments (posted not by me) are downvoted so much actually speaks for itself"* as referring to the broader situation of comments posted as answers being downvoted across Stack Overfow as a whole, not just the responses to this question. My mistake but you may want to disambiguate that a bit. That completely changes the perceived intent of your answer.

Comment: @ShamilAssylbekov: Please stop calling answers "comments", even answers to [discussion] questions on meta sites. Either they're *actually* comments and should be converted or deleted, or they aren't comments at all and the wrong terminology just confuses the issues. On main, answers <=3 score are faded out (unless you hover over them) because they are unreliable; on meta, answers <=8 get the same treatment because they're so thoroughly disagreed with.

Comment: @ShamilAssylbekov: Unless you have a specific explanation for why voting in a particular case is mistaken, it's extremely unwise to reject the votes of the community and assert that your own opinion should be substituted. Most of the time, votes mean that *multiple* thoughtful people considered an issue and came to particular conclusions, and there's usually no reason to assume they were significantly less competent to judge an argument's value than you are, except one's own natural ego. In short, if your opinion does not match others', seriously consider whether *you* might be wrong.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: There is a reason this thread exists. There is a reason this question got posted. There is a reason there is a similar looking reddit thread. There is a reason for all of this I am sure - regardless of my or your ego. There is a reason - whether you liked it a not - that I more than two years ago have independently googled "why is SO so hostile?" and google autocompleted my search query... Just saying...

Comment: And here we are a year later - and still having this discussion. Does it actually mean that this question has merit?

Comment: @ShamilAssylbekov: Alternate hypothesis: there are an awful lot of of people who are unable to distinguish "disagreement with ideas presented" from "personal hostility", or do not even accept that those *can* be distinguished. Given the trend toward "safe spaces" in colleges in the US these days (where rational discourse is censored heavily to avoid damaging the fragile psyches of students at large), this is a well-attested hypothesis.

Comment: It is quite evident that my opinion doesn't match yours and some others... And as for the majority... The majority of the electoral college voted for Trump. Well, guess what - I don't care anymore - so it doesn't matter - about the votes, donwvotes, badges etc. It is all not real. It doesn't exist. It doesn't matter - I have finally come to understand it. And I am free.

Comment: @ShamilAssylbekov: To be clear, though, I don't necessarily disagree that SO has problems with many of its users being unnecessarily hostile, or even that there are systemic problems in the site's processes or UI that contribute. But most of the candidates presented by the disgruntled are, to my mind, entirely innocent of the actual problems, and many of them are crucial to the site's operation.

Comment: @Nathan Tuggy: Or how about this: The original question has merit because it was posted by a human being and that human being said and I quote: _The gist of it is that people think that the community of Stack Overflow is hostile and unwelcoming._

Comment: "People" is ambiguous. Some "people" love this site. They understand the goal, the rules, the guidelines, the culture, etc. Other "people" don't care about our goal, the rules, the guidelines, or the culture. They think that we should put aside all of these things and cater to them and how they think it should be run. You make a change by being active in the community and voicing your opinions strategically. You don't make a change standing on the outside talking about it with other strangers. That said, there are some users who are more hostile and unwelcoming than others in any group.

Comment: Regardless of the rules and regulations - I am speaking from my own experience - I have had what I consider hostile encounters on SO when I was totally new to it. And you might have had totally different experiences. Let me put it this way for example: a white Caucasian male will hardly ever experience the same discrimination as an Asian female, or a black person. The fact that you have had good experiences doesn't negate that a substantial number of other users have had so called hostile encounters.

Comment: What does race or gender have to do with this? If you see references to race or gender, flag them as offensive.

Comment: Gender has everything to do with it. Most of programmers are male. Very few are black. Those are the gender and race statistics in the field. That is why I said that SO has the "people like us" problem.

Answer (score -9):

I think the problem is that there is insufficient dimensions in the grading of questions and answers. SO measures the quality of each question/answer with a single number (up/down votes). This is not enough. I believe we need more dimensions to the measure.

When I post a question on Meta for example, a downvote means something like *someone disagrees with my idea* not *this is a stupid question*. However, on SO, a downvote could mean anything from *oops! what the hell did I click on??** through *I hate this guy 'cause he trashed my answer yesterday* to *this is a stupid question*.

What new dimensions should be measured would probably be a topic for another thread. Perhaps *This answer was top on Google and helped me solve the same problem* and *Can't be bothered to comment but the advice here is stupid* might be candidates.

Answer (score -11):

**This** (not `*this`) is what is wrong with stackoverflow. I love this site, and the sister stackexchange sites.

That said, people have downvoted a [critical answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/298717/456814) to this question 46 times (and counting) mostly because it's critical. While I don't agree with that critical answer, the sentiment is right. stackoverflow.com and its sister sites are hostile as all get out, and getting more so by the day. A related site, physicsoverflow.org, was founded on the precept that hostility is a good thing (I'm not a member of that site). This site (and many of its sister sites) are emulating physics overflow, but in a passive-aggressive manner. In its favor, physics overflow is upfront and very aggressive about its stance. Behaviors at stackoverflow on the other hand are passive-aggressive in nature.

I no longer participate in flagging questions or answers. The atmosphere is far too hostile. I very rarely participate in any of the metas. The atmosphere here (and elsewhere) is even more hostile. I don't ask questions. Far too hostile. I've oftentimes wondered why anyone asks a question anymore. I no longer participate in the various reviews. It's a waste of effort. Those reviews should involve some amount of thought. By the time I've taken the time to think, five people eager to get that badge have already voted to approve the edit, or five soup nazis have already voted to close.

I'm a seasoned user on SO and across multiple SE sites. If I find things hostile, what is the new user to think?

Comment: So your suggestion to fix this is...? Also, its quite possible the 46 downvotes are because they don't agree with his solution.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET - I don't need to know how to fix this. When someone says you have a problem, you most likely have a problem. The idea that one can only report a problem if that person has as solution is downright destructive. This (speaking from experience) is what crashed the Columbia.

Comment: Regarding "*That said, people have downvoted a critical answer to this question 46 times (and counting) mostly because it's critical.*", see [Downvotes on Meta are confusing: do they *really* mean poor-post quality, or just disagreement?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254113/456814). People use downvotes to express a lot of different things on Meta. You can't assume that they're all downvoting something just because it's critical of SO. Maybe they're simply expressing disagreement. Meta downvotes encapsulate a broad swath of sentiment in a single action.

Comment: It is very awkward that this is a community wiki answer, rather than just a regular one. I can understand the sentiment that receiving downvotes feels sucky, but at least on Meta, they don't actually cost you anything (except maybe your pride), since Meta doesn't award reputation, nor take it away.

Comment: @Cupcake - I went through the Challenger and Columbia disasters. One thing NASA learned (or should have learned) is that when someone says "NASA, you have a problem", they should pay attention. The person identifying the problem should not be chastised for identifying the problem, and does not need to have a solution at hand. SO, you have a problem.

Comment: I guess the community here knows we have a problem. This question asks for ideas on how to solve it: *What sorts of systems or mechanisms can we think of to improve the quality of our community?*

Answer (score -14):

You need real data to address you question. Run a poll open to everyone-once-registered and get real statistics, that will help telling what people feel/think about the site.

Comment: A poll is a great way to get public perception, as filtered through the question (Asking so you get the answer you want irrespective of the facts is an art). But it's just about useless in getting to the facts.

Comment: @Deduplicator I must disagree. If the survey is done by an independent party, objectively, and following scientific methods, then it shouldn't be biased toward the answer you or others wanted.

Comment: Well, that's what one hopes. But here in the real world, especially with such emotional and soft targets, that's quite unlikely.

Comment: Don't be so dramatic @Deduplicator, with that view science wouldn't exist. Yet, here we are; trying at least.

Comment: Can someone smart explain to me why is this getting downvoted so much? Why is it a bad idea? When I see this answer getting downvoted like this - I just don't feel that SO is a safe place...

Answer (score -18):

Where there is smoke, there is fire.

TL;DR

I find SO both useful and hostile. And the CONs outweigh the PROs.

PROS:

The knowledge contained in it is useful. 
Some people are nice and helpful.

CONS:

1. The down voting is a form of trolling, bullying, similar to public shaming - ya know - that awful practice most of us in the real world don't support.
2. Deleting someone else's comments is a form of bullying as well,
   especially without having the need to explain your self.
3. Closing questions as duplicates when they aren't really duplicates, then reopening them, then closing them again, rinse, cycle, repeat is kind of an emotional roller coaster. I bet trolls enjoy it.
4. The system is too restrictive - very limited rights to newcomers,
   to a point where it is discouraging. Ain't nothing about it that is welcoming. Cmon, just be honest and admit that it is not welcoming, and it is Ok.
5. I don't know how content indexing is performed here, but the SO search is rather... underwhelming.

Comment: ["That city's littering laws are too strict. I'd leave, but for some reason every other city is covered in garbage."](https://twitter.com/drob/status/618120713522802688)

Comment: And that is fine. Just be honest and admit it. SO is too restrictive, therefore to some people it may appear to be hostile. Just saying.

Comment: And btw, I stumbled upon this post, after I googled "why is stackoverflow so hostile", which in turned was caused by earlier SO encounters. I thought I had a valid answer to two questions, and one of them got downvoted and deleted by a moderator (I don't know why), the other one was downvoted also almost immediately, and I myself deleted it thinking I don't want to look stupid. So, yeah, SO is hostile.

Comment: It's impossible to comment on that without seeing what your answers were. Either way - SO is a big city; you can have good experiences here, and occasionally (unfortunately) also bad experiences. If downvotes and closevotes mean nothing to you but "trolling" (rather than necessary quality control tools that can sometimes provide valuable feedback for improving your contributions, but are very imprecise and can sometimes be abused) then SO may not be the place for you, though.

Comment: By the way, the two essential actions on a Q&A site - asking and answering - can be performed by any user, regardless of how much reputation they have. That's worth noting. It would be really cool if the other actions could be unrestricted, too - and in the beginning, they were. The restrictions came as patterns of abuse emerged. [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173) is an attempt to explain the 50 rep comment barrier, for example.

Comment: Hopefully in the future things will get better, but not until they get worse first.

Comment: SO is way too permissive honestly, which is its problem. It lets anyone who can type some words into a box submit a question. Or post an answer. It would be _great_ if this wasn't the case...

Comment: That is exactly the elitist type of attitude, the us against them mentality, that is a problem for this platform in my subjective opinion. And it is ok, thank you for your honesty. You clearly don't think there is a problem, and everyone is entitled to their opinion, both sides of the argument. Wouldn't you agree?

Comment: For all y'all elitists who like to downvote things and think they are smarter than everyone else, don't like stupid questions and n00bs etc. etc. I have a PhD in physics, and I am not "anyone who can type some words in box to submit a question". In fact, just to give you a taste of your own disgusting medicine - I am probably smarter than you are, have higher IQ that you have, known more languages that you do etc. etc. And there, I did it, I had to stoop to your level for you to understand... Just kidding, you won't understand - I am positive about that. And I can say that I stopped using SO.

Comment: It has nothing to do with being smart. I'm no genius. It's about *respecting* that Stack Overflow has chosen to be more strict than other communities, we are happy with the decision, and it seems been a massive success. Not everyone is comfortable participating on those terms. That's fine: there are many other places online with looser rules for you to enjoy, without forcing you preferences on us. (I participate in some of them as well; it doesn't have to be one or the other, there's value in having different types of sites.) We're still happy to have you benefiting from the site as a reader.

Comment: It has everything to do with being smart, please. Of course it is about being smart... How, why, what? Why is it not about being smart? Is it about being stupid? I am somewhere on the autistic/genius spectrum and I can tell you that my experiences have been both somewhat positive, neutral and very very negative with SO. If I use SO anonymously as a reader - I like it - but I still don't like a lot of the comments and what I call "public shaming" of others. I don't want to engage in the community at all - and what I am doing now is just sort of venting...

Comment: And BTW, I am kind of hopeful - that the bullies will finally be gone... But not based on this particular thread... Please, do take time and read the comments/answers (not by me) and do explain why some of the answers here that are quite reasonable are downvoted so much... Just random explainable hope I have that it will get better...

Comment: Not agree with everything you said, but smoke = fire, definitively, yes. But they prefer to self-sabotage the community with denial. This crisis is the first one, but won't be the last one.

Answer (score -27):

Maybe if people were more interested in helping than in fixating on the format questions are written in, or the number of questions someone has asked.
This place doesn't seem to be about helping so much as insulting people who ask for help.

Comment: This place actually isn't about helping- That's just a side effect. The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a repository of _high quality_ programming questions. That's why there are people fixating on the format and presentation of the questions- They need to be helpful not only to you, the question asker, but also to future viewers who find your question in an attempt to answer their own. If that doesn't give you a good reason to worry about how well your question is written, consider this: The better formatted and presented your question is, the faster you'll likely get a good answer.

Comment: If you're having trouble with your questions being received well, by the way, try reading through the [ask] page in the help center. See if you can apply anything you pick up from there to your previous questions as well- If you make an edit, it will bump your question and get more eyes on it, and if the edit made the question higher quality, you can actually get upvotes for it. If the question is closed, a decent edit by you will throw it into the "Reopen Queue" which gives you a nice change to get it reopened.

Comment: Given the "quality" of the responses I've seen, it would seem you missed out somehow.
Impenetrable jargon, very dubious (mis)use of pronouns that make it almost impossible to figure out WTF someone is trying to say... assumptions that everyone is an expert so lots of important steps can be skipped...

Comment: "This place actually isn't about helping" Absolutely not. People don't have the culture here to try to guide the user when a question or an answer could be improved instead of being downvoted.

Answer (score -30):

#### Create a canonical section geared towards "new" users.

It's a huge concern to the current community that some people don't look up answers correctly and just create questions without abandon. Why not create a section geared towards those users so they don't ever create a new question in the first place?

Many answers could simply be corralled into a nice corner--canonical answers could have a special incentive for editing and being basically written towards these "low-quality" users. Many canonical questions might also get answers or such. Creating such a body of work geared towards new users would cause very little change to the system--simply create incentive to write articles geared towards new users, and we now have a body of work geared to build up people's knowledge of programming, and even better, SO's style, demeanor, and quality standards.

**Edit**: **Yes, that link to the meta question was very helpful. I'm closing this answer because the issue is correctly addressed in the other question. More people deserve to read it.**

Comment: `Why not create a section geared towards those users so they don't ever create a new question in the first place?` but we have that - the "search" field to the top right. The problem is that people aren't using it.

Comment: The problem with a section for 'new' users is that those that answer questions *won't go there*. So you only get inexperienced newbies answering these questions. What this'll lack is quality answers.

Comment: The various communities **already** create canonical answers for newbies. Look at [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658) for example. The problem is that *some users don't use search*. And then complain that we were rude when we dupe-vote to close their question.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Note that some programmers might not even understand what exactly they need to look for--they might not even know the correct search terms to look for. A "linking vs compiling" problem could be unknown to a complete beginner, and the terminology might still be too thick for one.

Comment: There is also the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [help], complete with a first page with a *checkbox* you need to check to acknowledge you'll take the help offered to heart. But there is always a group of people that won't read those and not search and *still complain loudly*.

Comment: @VermillionAzure: is such a user and/or question the type we 'want' on "a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers"?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Why not formalize it and have it grow further? It seems like a good standard to adapt.

Comment: @Vermillion re complete beginners - true, but the canonical answer to that is that *they shouldn't be on Stack Overflow, they should be consulting with the basic teaching resource of their choice.* Think of SO as a University; if you ask a grade school question at University, you will be asked to leave. Sometimes politely, sometimes no so much.

Comment: We are fine with the *not knowing the terms* questions; they can be well written, and we then close those as a duplicate and they act as signposts for the next person searching. That system works just fine. :-)

Comment: @VermillionAzure: Because of the law of diminishing returns; the system has already been adapted and has already been grown. What you see then is a loud minority that refuses to see what is in place to help newcomers.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But I must make the counter argument that even universities have been shifted to lower their standards to cater to the masses. There are sub-100-level classes (at least in the US) that exist to cater to these people. For some, they are necessary. Does this mean that universities shouldn't have sub-100-level classes?

Comment: @VermillionAzure it means *we* as a community don't want sub-100-level classes. Because they don't work in a Q&A context and don't serve the site's main goal, to create canonical Q&A.

Comment: @Pekka웃 But then this might imply that we should make a second Stack Exchange website or opt for a different system. I've already made a proposal for another site to cater to these people, but it was rejected and closed.

Comment: @VermillionAzure I don't think you'll find a following for such a site on Meta because the general belief around here is that it would become a gigantic pile of crap before soon - that it would drown in "I need to do x please send code" type input. I'm not excluding the possibility that there *is* a way to do this right, but it seems unlikely that SE will embark on that journey.

Comment: @Pekka웃 mmm, yes. I do agree.

Comment: There is a widespread and (in my mind) inexplicable belief, which is also stated in the Medium article you posted, that Stack Overflow somehow has a *duty* to be the home of programming-related questions if they don't have their own Stack Exchange site. This is, of course, patently false and unsustainable. We have a deliberately narrow scope and a high set of standards because the scale that SO operates at is *enormous* and things would fall apart otherwise. These are core beliefs that simply won't be compromised on.

Comment: @ChrisHayes I'd argue that something needs to be done, but now I see that SO just isn't the place for it. This has been a great discussion!

Comment: I agree with the idea that things might be better in a global sense if something was done - that is, if somewhere on the internet there was a site catering to these types of questions. I just don't agree with the concept that Stack Exchange should be the ones to do it. A lot of the questions that lead to things like the Medium article are just plain not fit for a tightly focused Q&A format, and need a proper discussion board. (As an aside, I really appreciate your open attitude. Almost every question we get like this on meta goes extremely badly right off the bat.)

Answer (score -41):

I would do <strike>two</strike> three things:

1. Get rid of downvoting on questions.
2. Invest heavily in policing comments, perhaps by giving higher-rep
   users the ability to remove offensive comments directly rather than
   simply flagging them.
3. Allow all users to see close votes so that downvotes are not needed to
   signal quality problems

I don't believe that downvoting of questions is materially important and it often serves as a mechanism for purely negative feedback, particularly for new users. I understand the value in removing bad questions but there are two strategies for that: removal and improvement.  Downvoting is effective only at the first and we already have the ability to close and delete questions. Downvoting does not, at least with any real effectiveness, encourage people to improve the questions. Generally it only makes people feel bad about their experience.

In my experience comments on poor questions, while some help the asker by pointing towards resources or asking clarifying questions, generally fall into the class that I would call bullying.  At the very least they don't move the conversation forward. I'd like to see this aspect of the culture change and I think it starts with a zero-toleration policy for comments that aren't helpful. Today I routinely flag these when I see them.  I'd like to see it go further and emphasize how destructive these are by giving higher-rep users more ability to directly delete these - perhaps with some negative consequences for those whose comments are frequently deleted.

I recently had the privilege to talk to some aspiring developers about Stack Overflow. While they recognize and use Stack Overflow as a resource, their primary concerns were about being perceived as stupid and having a negative experience if they asked questions.  You can not learn effectively if you're afraid to ask questions and for many new users, that is is the experience that Stack Overflow has become: fear.

I get the broken window theory - but if I can take the metaphor a little further - we also need to be concerned about the roving gangs of vigilantes who bully people, thinking that they are planning to break a window when they only want to look inside.

Comment: Not a fan of removing downvotes for questions; but I like the investing more heavily in policing comments. So much so [I've talked about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180082/16587) [twice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180325/16587) on Meta.   With that in mind, I get why you want downvotes removed; and I hope there's a way to bridge the gap between "Identify and destroy crap" (which we see a lot of) and "not penalize users who mean well but don't quite get it."

Comment: In terms of comment moderation on rude comments, my experience has been that abusive comments are very quickly removed by moderators when flagged. The "rude or offensive" comment flag queue regularly sits at or near 0 in the moderator tools. The problem would appear to be one of identification of rude comments and patterns of these, more than it is acting on them. Even if we let the community handle these, they wouldn't be able to move on them faster than we can. We either need to educate more people about comment flagging or have a better way of finding rude comments.

Comment: @BradLarson partly I view the creation of the ability as a strong and public stand against such comments.  It's not the comment itself per se but a culture that allows people to feel free to post them that needs to change.

Comment: One way to do this might be to have a kind of comment review queue, similar to the various post review queues we have now. This would also help to identify spam comments (which slip through more frequently than I would like, and can live on the site for months until someone flags them). If done right, we might even be able to expand comment privileges to new users and remove the 50-rep barrier that frustrates some of the people commenting in the above-linked articles.

Comment: how about we redirect downvote arrow from down to somewhere else. And change tooltip to something like "this post lacks just a little bit to be totally awesome"

Comment: @Brad Larson: With the kind of performance we're seeing from post reviewers I honestly don't think this is going to work well at all. I'm not even going to try to be sarcastic about it.

Comment: @BoltClock - For all that we joke about it, review works incredibly well to identify spam, trolling, etc. coming in via new users. We all point at the places where it fails, but in the vast majority of cases, reviewers correctly identify spam when it comes in front of them. There is no such exposure to comments right now, so only if you happen across a post or are involved in it can you even have the opportunity to flag truly abusive content. I really do believe that more eyeballs on comments would lead to much better moderation here.

Comment: @Brad Larson: Do you think users will be better at deleting comments than creating them? Also, if such a queue were made it'd have to be far better than what we have right now (which is poor at the one thing that matters: showing context).

Comment: @GeorgeStocker what purpose does downvoting serve that close votes don't? Is that worth the negativity communicated by downvotes?

Comment: @tvanfosson I wish people voted to close more. We don't have enough of it. I wish we did. But I also wish we had better ways of getting OPs to fix the issues when their questions are closed.  This is a deep problem, and it needs a lot of work to fix.

Comment: Downvotes are anonymous, close votes are not.

Comment: Close votes don't signal quality (primarily), they signal scope and if it's on topic. Downotes signal quality (primarily), which isn't the same as scope or being on topic

Comment: @random - but aren't we agreed that we only want high quality questions? in my experience, if it's worth voting down, it's worth closing.  You can still distinguish quality by relative upvotes. The difference between 0 and negative votes seems like it's not worth the negativity communicated to new users.

Comment: Here's a thought experiment for you: what if instead of downvoting questoins, anyone (with some rep on the site) could close or reopen any question with a single vote? How would the experience differ for new users?

Comment: Or another one, the new users are not shown the downvotes on their question, only seeing 0 or upvotes, but everyone sees the real count. After the user notches 100 EXP, then they can see the reality

Comment: @Shog9 with the "on hold" language I think it would improve it.  What we're aiming for (I think) is a culture where people are encouraged to participate and ask *good* questions. Putting a question on hold - coupled with some specific advice about how to improve it - communicates "hey, I see you're having a problem but you need to frame your question better in order to get a good response."  Downvoting, to me, has a connotation of  "you did something bad." It's not a very good experience.

Comment: @random but then how will the user know their question needs to be improved?

Comment: @tvanfosson Putting a question on-hold requires 5 votes (and then 5 more to re-open). Downvoting *immediately* sends a signal that "hey, people are seeing this, but you are doing it wrong!" In theory, the votes would be reversed or cancelled by later votes after good edits (of course, this happens far too infrequently) without having to go through the close/re-open process.

Comment: The same is true of a single close vote.

Comment: @tvanfosson How can a single close vote help a new user? They can't see the close vote like they can the downvote. You can't see close votes on your own question until you have 250 rep. What about the multitude of users with less reputation than that? For them, it's as Bradley's said: Even a single downvote warns them something's off. Until 250 rep, they need 5 close votes to know something's wrong, yet only one or two downvotes to get a message something's not right. (I assume at such a high rep for what I assume to be a while, you didn't realize that rep limit was a thing.)

Comment: You're correct, I didn't realize that you couldn't see close votes until 250 rep.  That seems counterintuitive as those are the people who most need to see them.  I've adjusted my answer to address this.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Yes, those are the people who most need to see them. But they are also the people who need most protection from false signals, and who are most likely to react wrong to them either way, most likely by panicing or investing in a strong offense against those trying to help.

Comment: "In terms of comment moderation on rude comments, my experience has been that abusive comments are very quickly removed by moderators when flagged. " Except when they are from the moderators, and except when they are subtile enough to only be disdainful.