# This question of mine was downvoted, but I read rules and think it fits them

Tags: discussion, scope, downvote-reason, opinion-based

EDIT: I'm not complaining for it, I'm politely asking if it fits rules or not, please just comment without touching that downvote button...

EDIT 2: My question is different that the previous one, because while the other post was clearly against rules (I realized it later), I think for this one that it fits rules. I quoted them, so if it doesn't please comment and tell me which rules it doesn't it fit. There is a huge quote here on posts like mine on Parse

Today [this question of mine which was un-voted for 3 months, has been downvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30693340/would-you-recommend-overall-parse-com-for-a-big-scale-project).
I think it's related to the previous post I did on meta, and somebody seeing my questions downvoted it as it's opinion-based.

Now, I'm not gonna write a post here everytime a question of mine gets downvoted, just I still have some difficults sometimes to understand fully the rules.

In [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), it's clearly readable:

> Some subjective questions are allowed, but “subjective” does not mean “anything goes”. All subjective questions are expected to be constructive. What does that mean? Constructive subjective questions:
>
> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
> - have a constructive, fair, and impartial tone
> - invite sharing experiences over opinions
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references
> - are more than just mindless social fun

Now, I think my question, still being partially subjective, fits all the points listed, because Parse has changed much over the time, and while this is my first big project with it as backend, many people in the past had troubles with it, while recently it's getting better. So I asked more for facts than opinions.

I was asking so for a recommendation (that it looks like almost forbidden in this site), but knowing it at the time, I put this clear clause in my question

> **Now, if you ever used Parse for something big, would you recommend me it?**

Also,  I wrote this

> Please provide every answer with objective factors, as said, though this question is opinion-based too, I'd like it to remain also based on real factors. I'd also like to have some claryfing about requests/second and total users, since I never had an online-based app with so many users.

Indeed, I got only 1 quality-answer, not dozen of answers like "No, I don't like it; Yes, I love it".

Since here there are the people who want to guarantee SO posts' quality, could you tell me if I'm right when saying that my 3-months ago post fits rules or not?

Comment: complaining about being downvoted in the question is akin to asking for more downvotes.

Comment: No, I'm asking if it fits or not the rules to people that are more experts than me at this.

Comment: Well, that's called the [Meta effect](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269349/what-is-the-meta-effect). If you're exposing yourself to the community in a broader way, you should be aware of more attention and critiques coming along.

Comment: What Kevin says is that your edit asking why this post is being downvoted without comments will only attract further downvotes...

Comment: Well, you see, people downvote for a wide variety of reasons, some justified, some not. Fortunately (or, unfortunately for you i guess,) we aren't required to justify our votes. If we want to help you improve the post, we'll leave a comment. Some may feel that the post simply can't be improved because of the type of response you're looking for.

Comment: But I read rules and I think the post fits them, what do you think about it?

Comment: Gave you an upvote, ill carry on...

Comment: My gut feeling is that it doesn't fit that well.  It's a fairly broad question, and it touches some non-traditional programming aspects (like worth of value in terms of real money).  Although I will say that you've been fairly clear, and it seems you've researched it, so the downvotes are probably proxies for close votes.  That happens sometimes.

Comment: It's an edge case. Some people will see the question as fine, others won't. I in particular don't like the question because it's asking for an opinion, and i find opinions to be pretty useless in programming.

Comment: Still if the backend is reliable or not, that's not just an opinion. And spending hundred of hours on developing a game on a backend that could be not reliable is an important thing, and thus I think it justifies the opinion-based question. Also I asked to raise facts together opinions, and indeed there wasn't an opinion fight or things like that, so I think my post was pretty qualitied.

Comment: @user1714647 it's of decent quality.  Whether it's on-topic is pretty iffy.  That's probably why the downvotes are there.

Comment: Bjorn that's my post lol

Comment: @user1714647 lol, I know.

Comment: People are keeping downvoting my original post (the one about Parse). It's sad to see that even when it looks like my post fits rules it gets still downvoted. I think I'm gonna delete that too. Please upvote it if you think it fits rules, at least bring it back to 0

Comment: please note that deleted questions still count toward the question ban/rate limiting system (possibly worse than undeleted questions.) deletion should be a last resort.

Comment: You can't delete a question if it has an upvoted answer.

Comment: sorry... but begging for upvotes "so we can bring it back to 0" is NOT appropriate... at ALL..

Comment: I don't care if I get banned if just for asking a thing I get tons of downvotes

Comment: You're asking for stuff that is on the line of on topic/off topic, and bring it to meta.... yeah, it won't end up well unfortunately... Meta effect and all

Comment: I know that it's not appropriate, but people who think the post isn't good are downvoting, the others are doing nothing (if there are others). I think if it fits the rules and I'm asking if I'm right, and I'm AGAIN only getting downvotes without any explanation at all, not even on meta

Comment: But the rules are clear on accepted opinionbased posts. Facts > Opinions

Comment: This meta zone is to discuss, why people just downvote my posts even here?

Comment: yes, but people can also vote whichever way they want. So when you are on the edge of on/off topic, you will get grumpy people who downvote... and since it's not GREAT, maybe not that many people to upvote (and let's PLEASE FOR THE LOVE OF ZALGO stop discussing downvotes on meta... now I'm ok just pinning the downvotes here to you complaining about the downvotes here....)

Comment: because people throw downvotes around like candy on meta.

Comment: What do you mean no explanation. The downvote tooltip says "this post shows no research effort, is unclear or not useful" Why does every downvoter need to repeat that?

Comment: @user1714647 People are downvoting because of disagreement, as it already was mentioned to you.

Comment: Downvoting should never be encouraged. My post can not be the best question in this site but it's not trash to deserve so many downvotes (the one about Parse). I checked the rules, again, and it looks like it fits them. You want to downvote? Do it, but please tell me why, because I CAN'T understand it.

Comment: Well the fact you ask "can I afford that package with the amt of users needed to do 600 req/sec" is pretty much SUPER opinionated... depends on how much you charge for you app, WHAT your app does, how often it does it, the distribution of customers throughout the world... Yeah I'd say that sentence isn't helping you out in the post.

Comment: If that's not asking for opinions, I don't know what is. You're expected to do your own research for these sorts of questions. If its important, hire a consultant, because that's what they're for.

Comment: That question may be "opinionated", but still I asked for people who had EXPERIENCE in Parse, so every experienced feedback could have been useful to me and to other people. And I think this justifies the question. Besides, as the rules say, answers on my post tend to be long (even if there is only 1) and not short

Comment: Downvoting is useful because it indicates to others that a question is not useful. If we left it other users would see it and say "Why can't I ask this kind of question?, that guy got away with it"

Comment: I got that @Robert but again, for the HUNDREDTH time, I read rules, I think my post fits them. You are saying "no it doesn't because it asks for opinion", I'm saying "it requires above all facts, like the rules want" and you guys are replying "no it requires opinions, because of reasons, oh, downvoted btw"

Comment: And we get that you disagree with the rest of us.

Comment: ok.... how is "can i afford a package that gives me 600 req/sec with the amount of users needed to generate 600 req/sec" anything BUT opinionated? It's SO dependent on so many different factors....

Comment: You aren't actually giving a reason. You're saying my post is not ok but not explaining why, that's why I disagree. I said it fits apparently what rules say. You're saying "no it doesn't" but w/o providing any evidence of it. So how can I not disagree?

Comment: Patrice I removed that sentence. Now is my post more ok? Since it's not completely unsavable, but for me it looks good enough, can you say what other is wrong and at least try to support me on it (I'm not begging for upvotes, just I got 4 downvotes for writing this post)?

Comment: We are. We're saying its opinion based, which it really is. The fact that you think it's still allowed is overruled by the community's decision that they think it's not.

Comment: It's opinion based but not primarily opinon-based. I'm asking for opinions evidenced by facts. You can't just say if Parse is reliable or not. You **have to** share your experience with it, to evidence proofs, numbers and things.

Comment: Not sure it's salvageable... even in the answer given to you... "from what I can tell, it's pretty solid now"... solid? WHAT is solid? and how do you not see "from what I can tell" as being an opinion-based answer?

Comment: You asking for specific requirements in no way obligates answerers to obey those requirements, nor does it make an opinion based question acceptable.

Comment: The answer was above all good.. Yes, that can be an opinion, but it's also true that many critics on parse are too outdated, so I looked for people which had RECENT experience with it.

Comment: @fbueckert still there wasn't a shitstorm of opinionbased comments, so I think my specific requirements were **effective** to keep the post qualitied

Comment: ... you seem to come back to the point of "but I need it, so it HAS to be on topic"... which is just wrong for Stack

Comment: Irrelevant. The question *must* stand on its own, and adding words to bypass close reasons doesn't work. The fact that you want recent experiences gives you no power to enforce such answers, and its still an opinion based question.

Comment: You know what, I'm deleting the post anyway. THANKS for **ruining** completely my experience on this site. I quoted rules to EVIDENCE the fact I'm right, you're just saying "no it doesn't" without putting ANYTHING in evidence. fbu it didn't give me the power but worked.

Comment: One of the other reasons for avoiding opinionish questions is that in general they will have inherently time dependent answers. So for instance, if you had have asked this exact question a year ago would you get the same answers as today? Will you get the same answer in a year? Will the answers you get today help the user that googles and finds this question and it's answers in a year? Subjective answers are more likely to change over time.

Comment: @user1714647 again, you focus on ONE guy and say "BUT THIS IS WRONG"... you realize my points were not debated? in fact, in my points I tell you "this is an opinion in an answer" and you basically answer "yes"...

Comment: You're not linking the rules, you're not saying anything helpful. Nice to see that years ago, [primarily based posts were highly upvoted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11283729/how-scalable-is-parse). Btw  don't think I write questions just to gather upvotes, just I looked for help and thanks to you I didn't get it.

Comment: *Some subjective questions are allowed* - This does not take precedence over the rule against recommendation questions. Your question is still asking SO to recommend an external service, which is off topic.

Comment: Patrice I said it's opinion based but still the opinions must be evidenced by facts which is more important. Even the rules say that, you're just saying "it's opinon based, it's opinion based, it's opinion based"

Comment: It might have worked this time, but that just means you got lucky. Site policy can't be based on luck. It's specific policy that has to be applied equally, magic word syndrome notwithstanding.

Comment: but @user1714647 but the user has NO facts to back up his information, he says "to me this is solid enough"... he provides NO FACTS, only opinions...

Comment: Please just vote to delete that. I'm done with these posts. Thank you for not being helpful at all, instead all the opposite.

Comment: This new policy where fitting PERFECTLY the rules is the priority over helping people feels just wrong for me.

Comment: @user1714647 you came here ASKING, you got solutions. The fact it's not the solution you feel ENTITLED to isn't a proof we're not helpful. Might be a proof you don't fully get how Stack works yet?

Comment: @user1714647 I feel like I've told you that on your other post, but stack isn't a place to get help. It's a repository of knowledge. The help it provides is a side effect of that (and the format used to deliver the knowledge). Over time, Stack got SO popular because people get help by browsing the site, users tend to forget that this was never the intended purpose, and still isn't.

Comment: I'd recommend re-reading the good subjective, bad subjective blog post. It might help you learn the criteria for what passes for opinionated questions.

Comment: I said that I don't fully understand here rules because it's not just about reading but also about experience on this site, which you guys have lot more over me. Again, my post could not fit perfectly the rules, ok I accept that, still I don't think it ruins this site quality and still I think I didn't deserve all those downvotes on it. If you now wanna make me happier (if you even care), just vote to delete that one because really I don't care anymore to discuss for it.

Comment: you realize you come, get help, stomp your feet because it's not the help you feel you should be given, and leave angry? twice it happened TODAY... maybe it's time to review your attitude?

Comment: Is that a thing of your concern? Why do you care if I leave angry or not. I'm now asking a last thing, vote to delete that post and we're good. The way you "give help" is not the way help is intended in the vocabulary. You are not helping me twice, you are blaming me twice for not getting the rules that you got after years of active experience in this site.

Comment: years? I've been an active user for a bit more than a year (started last august). In any case, you do look like someone who GENUINELY wants to get help, when he doesn't feel offended by a meaningless number besides his post. So yes I'm trying to genuinely help you get why this is happening (and giving you hints on other parts of the site you may not be familiar with, like the rules of meta). With that point of view in mind, I do care a little that you see the help for what it is and not leave angry because you disagree

Comment: And I NEVER blamed you... stop thinking comments are FOR or AGAINST you.... stop thinking EVERYTHING and EVERYONE is against you... that would help

Comment: I think that everyone is against me in the moment I politely ask for claryfing and get 10 downvotes on this post and 7 in the linked one. Don't tell me they're just meaningless because that doesn't give me the help I wanted, and you're not doing it either since I quoted rules and you actually didn't quote anything except "nope, it's not like that"

Comment: Seems like I've quoted your question and answer, thus validating what I say, since it does kinda prove points I'm making.... anyway, see it the way you want, I think in the end if qe don't tell you "oh you're right and we'll upvote you" you'll still stomp your feet and argue. Anyway I do believe you need to cool off and stop seeing posts ans comments as "against you"

Comment: You received 12 downvotes, from 53 views. that's hardly everyone.

Comment: I told the cops, "Look, I said directly to the dealer that I was not interested in taking part in any illegal transactions, and that if he wanted to initiate one that I would not take part. So, when I gave him cash for that vial of crack, it was totes legal. See?" and I totally got away with it.  brb, crack.

Comment: [This.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298693/ideas-for-proposals-to-help-stack-overflow-create-a-more-positive-community)

Comment: You *are* aware that Meta post is based on a false premise, are you not? Complaining about negativity and cherry picking examples to.prove your point doesn't actually help your argument.

Comment: Seriously shut up, this community has become lame as few. As if resolving a question would make this site worse. Stop saying nonsense.

Comment: @user1714647 look at my latest comment on the answer here. YES answering one question could potentially make this site worse. YOU keep on using examples of cherry picked bad questions that have been received decently to prove that your questions shouldn't be downvoted/closed.... if YOUR question gets answered, then how can we explain to the next new user that it isn't up to standards and they shouldn't ask a similar question?

Comment: Many quality questions of this site have been against the rules and eventually closed, but still highly upvoted. That doesn't mean the site is more ruined, also I'd have got help from an existent question similar mine. I think I'll ask on gamedev where they mind less about "oh look somebody wants to ruin this place". And about the troll thing is true. Many people here are just SO trolls who care more about blaming people than helping them.

Comment: @user1714647 and the argument can be made that you use those questions against the rules to justify your own questions that don't follow the rules.... so yeah, I do think in a way, letting SOME bad questions fly will hurt the site in the long run. And feeling entitled to help on Stack is not the proper way to see how the site works. As long as you have that mindset about "stack is there to help me", there's NO argument we make that can sway you. It's not even a disagreement. You don't see the site for what it is.

Comment: You take too seriously the questions (as I take too seriously the downvotes). A question that seems useless and subjective for 5 users (which is enough to close the question) can be useful for 20 others. You can never know that. And for the game question (not the Parse one), maybe I was asking for a recommendation, but the number of easy solutions may be so limited that the question could not be too broad.

Comment: Good thing you actually need an investment in the site before you can participate in reopening questions. That's a privilege that's *earned*. Popularity != on-topic. The point is that what you asked isn't acceptable. Throwing a tantrum about it doesn't help you one bit. **You** have to adapt to the community, not the other way around.

Comment: @user1714647 I take questions too seriously? on a QUESTIONS and answer site? Correct me if I'm wrong but the WHOLE point of this site is to have good questions and the corresponding good answers. If you want a help-desk like website, get a contract coder on retainer. I feel like beating a dead horse ("horse beaten enough it was turn to mush" actually) by telling you you seem to think this site OWES you answers... Stop seeing it as that, see it for what it is, the rest will start making sense. If I go to a car dealership convinced his car should fly, I CANNOT appreciate his car, no matter what.

Comment: This [question](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101465/how-to-create-a-map-from-graph) on GameDev is not from mine, but it's similar to the one I did in StackOverflow. They got the same rules as SO has, and look how the question was upvoted, answered and not closed.

That question HELPED me, and in StackOverflow you can't do that "because of perfectly 101% fitting rules blah blah blah".

Answer (score 12):

That question doesn't fit the rules as you like to see them.

It is overly broad, opinion based and not very useful for future visitors as answers would likely only be valid for you.

Such questions can work if you ask about the actual problem you're trying to solve. The only reasonable thing to ask would be something along these lines:

> I'm using Parse.com and would like to keep using the free plan as long as possible. For that I need to request to stay below 30 per second if I want to serve more than 1000 users. I have the following code to keep requests low
>
> ```
>   FuBar req= Parse.magic!23{cache}@
> ```
>
> but in my testing it shows that this doesn't invalidate the cache. How can I add that? I'm not required to use Parse btw

What could happen when you ask that question that answers show you possible ways to keep the number request low, share state, tweak some settings or users suggest a different tool stack  that offers similar functionality with a better free plan.

Looking at all your questions so far on SO ( and the two on meta today) you seem to focus on getting answers that are useful for you. That is not the point of Stack Overflow, or any SE site for that matter. We don't care about how your question is going to help you.

Your question has to be able to help future visitors.

Opinion based, broad questions aren't helpful for visitors that arrive on your question by a google search. Not that many will find them self in the same situation as you. After all this site is for practical answerable questions that have some code in it.

Comment: _"Your question has to be able to help future visitors."_ I believe this is the most important point made in your answer.

Comment: So [if someone asks how to declare an array in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1200621/declare-array-in-java) does a more legit and qualitied question that mine. Feels legit.

Comment: How to declare an array is a specific, *objective* question, in a specific language. Is it simple? Yep. Still extremely objective.

Comment: But it lacks research cause a 30-sec research on google would give you better result than how users can give you in answers, or also a book. So it's objective? But lacks research. While mine question, didn't actually lack of it.

Comment: And is **six years old**. Standards have since changed. I doubt it would get the same response today as it did when it was asked.

Comment: Third time you link old questions. ... will you listen to us when we say they can't be used to defend newer questions?

Comment: There still isn't a rule against posting easy questions. It's just far less common for an easy question to not be a duplicate now.

Comment: It can be how many years old you want, for me it feels dumb because it shows totally no efforts in searching things on own. Kevin but there is a rule about showing also proper work instead of asking

Comment: Yes, which will get you downvotes, not closure. A downvoted question can still be answered and eventually turn around to positive over time if it is useful to enough people.

Comment: Sure because if people here throw downvotes like popcorn to pigeons, having almost 10 downvotes on a SO question (not meta) will FOR SURE help me in the future to get upvotes. 100% not to get it deleted (as it indeed was)

Comment: The java question you linked to, it has ***30*** downvotes.

Comment: and a balance of **743** upvotes and 156 favorites. I think the upvotes are for the people who give a simple answer and get too hundreds of ups. It looks like a kind of point trading for Qer & Aers

Comment: Something like, you put a dumb question? I put an obvious answers. 1000 upvotes for each. And that's considered more quality than how my Parse post was.

Comment: Yah but see this is kinda symptomatic of how you interact with the site... because YOU don't feel the rule makes.sense, you go against it... same things with your questions. .. we tell you they don't fit, you say they do...

Comment: I quoted rules, you're just saying that I say things.

Comment: You quoted the rules, and think your question follows them. Some of us don't think it follows them. It's simply a disagreement. we're both quoting the same rules.

Comment: @user1714647 Again. Focusing on other questions as a justification to keep yours isn't going to work. At the end of the day, yours is completely opinion based, and there's no way to salvage it to make it acceptable.

Comment: You should have quoted the part of the rules which my Q disagreed, because part I quoted looked like it totally agreed.

Comment: I think your question does follow the rules that you quoted, but i still feel it is of low quality. however, i do not vote on questions brought up in meta.

Comment: And at the end of the day, that question is completely dumb and awarded mathematically an infinite times more than mine (since I got even downvoted).

Comment: Who knows, if I find a rare and uncommon language, and ask how to declare an array in it I may be awarded too, because that's considered more helping for the others that actually asking for REAL troubles.

Comment: My issue with your question is it's length. It's way too wordy, is missing a summary as the first paragraph, contains the word "recommend" way too many times (and shouldn't be in the title, that alone will attract downvotes, warranted or not)

Comment: Rather than throwing a tantrum that your question was closed, why don't you accept constructive criticism, and learn from it? You'll get a much better reception here.

Comment: Instead of asking if people would recommend it, ask if the claims against it can be proven. That certainly would be objective and possibly even useful. You can then use that information to decide if it's right for you (because only you should make that decision)

Comment: Still people would downvote it as opinion-based and flag to close/delete it. If 1 question requires opinions I don't think that this site quality suffers, but this seems to be your priority lastly so...

Comment: Site quality is the *primary* concern. Always has been. That's the whole point of curating the site.

Comment: @user1714647 you're aware you've been using OTHER questoons to defend your own? So letting yours fly because "one question won't hurt the site" means we now will have people linking your question as an example.... so it WILL hurt the site...