# Really off-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope, site-recommendation

I was aware of the off-topic rule before I posted [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682175/need-a-bbcode-parser-for-php-after-multiple-tries-with-already-invented-wheels) and I must say that if it was a recommendation thread, I wouldn't be here because it would mean I had a choice.
I thought my question was more a:
criterion 1
criterion 2
criterion 3
_tried a dozen of extensions (am stuck since months with that problem) but not one fit my criteria (I posted an appendix about why it failed in case I missed something > I also did it to show people that I made some research)

I thought it wasn't off-topic because it's specific, researched and it's not about choices or best *something* but more a "does it exist?" question. "Does criterion 1+2+3 = something?" I am not asking for opinions.
My first try seemed to have "rambling" in it and the question diluted in superfluous comment so I removed that.

Now, am I still off-topic? If that's the case, can I edit my question in a way that I can avoid that. If it's not possible, is there some other communities that could fit my request or am I stuck with my problem for life?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it's off topic and for the reason indicated. Understand that "off-topic" does not necessarily mean that yours is a "bad question" or that you are a "bad questioner", but rather just that the question topic is not one that is allowed on this site. If you still need help, Google an appropriate site, and ask there.

Comment: _**" is there at least one existing customizable BBCode parser that can fit that set of criteria? If that's the case, which one? I am not asking for the BEST plugin, just link me ONE, if that's even possible."**_ You're asking for finding a 3rd party resource, that's explicitely off-topic.

Comment: Ok, I thought you could be on-topic by avoiding broad recommandation and ask the problem as something really specific and detailed but if it's the rule, it's the rule. Understand Hovercraft Full Of Eels that if google could have helped me, I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Also note that meta voting is different from other StackOverflow sites. A down-vote here does not mean that someone thinks you've posted a poor meta question, but rather just that they disagree with your question's premise.

Comment: see also: [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)

Comment: *I thought you could be on-topic by avoiding broad recommandation and ask the problem as something really specific and detailed* - That's actually a rule at Software Recommendations. I see that Shog already suggested it but you definitely want to click on that link for their [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) as well. Those are not optional.

Answer (score 12):

So your question is either,

> #### How can I translate BBCode to HTML without allowing unlimited nesting?

(which is on-topic for Stack Overflow *if* you're thorough and share your research)

**OR** your question is,

> ### I want a BBCode renderer that meets my exact specifications

(which is totally off-topic for Stack Overflow, but you could ask on [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic))

I'd go with the former, myself. It doesn't sound like you actually need to support the full BBCode syntax, which means you could write this yourself without too much trouble. Which kinda fits into the whole, "specific programming problem" thing that Stack Overflow does so well.

But if you're determined to use an off-the-shelf library *and* are convinced such a library exists... Then Stack Overflow is the wrong place to look for it.

Comment: Let say that BBCode is everywhere and it's unbelievable to me that there is not a single parser in the world that can fit what I think is common sense when you are parsing BBCode (as I am using BBCode everyday). I am not too confident in my skill, moreover I fear that a homemade bbcode couldn't fit basic performance requirement. I already tried to make one after so many attempts and got weird errors hence my lack of self-confidence. I might be forced to post my homemade parser here (if I not locked) but I thought, like in every threads I read, I would get the "don't reinvent the wheel" answer.

Comment: Nothing new under the sun, right? Problem is, you don't know whether the parser you want is lurking on Github or in someone's private repository somewhere or in a throwaway routine that someone posted to a message board (wrapped in a BBCode [code] block of course) back in '09 and long ago forgotten about. Also, you don't know that it isn't incredibly slow because it was written by someone who never learned proper string parsing. All you know is that you can describe how it should work... Which, honestly, is the hardest part. Have some confidence in your own abilities... This ain't rocket sci.

Comment: People need to learn the hopeless truth. That's also why I asked that kind of question : to be sure I had no other choice but to code my own parser even if it will be a bad one.