# Badge for rewording closed off-topic questions and voting to reopen

Tags: discussion, badges, vote-to-reopen

Today I went to Stack Overflow to see how to implement a state of the art WebSocket Server compatible with HTML5 WebSocket clients. I was interrested about how to do that either in Python or C++.

I was happy to find good answers on both subjects:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916217/standalone-c-or-c-websocket-server-library
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5839054/websocket-server-in-python

Both questions are giving a good starting point to find out how to implement WebSocket protocol using existing libraries. No need to reinvent the whell isn't it?

What is worrying me is that both questions have been closed with the following reason:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software
>   library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack
>   Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.
>   Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve
>   it.

The answers to these questions are not opinionated neither spam. The trouble (and likely the reason these questions were closed) is that implementation of such features will logically use some existing library. That will be the natural move of any skilled professional.

As I read it, the questions ask for a way to solve **a specific programming problem**, thus the questions are specifically **on topic** and very useful... nevertheless they have been closed on the basis of a very broad close reason about pitfalls of referencing existing software libraries.

I agree that in some cases such questions can lead to pointless discussions of the "best library or tool" to perform some specific task. Yet it's still better than nothing. We can also see that the questions I pointed to did not raise much spam or opinion-based answers, but useful content.

Of course, the question can be rephrased to describe the problem (here "Implement a WebSocket server"), but it's so much easier to close the question instead, so that I believe rephrasing will be the exception instead of the rule.

It is especially annoying that such questions are closed, because it merely forbids to update answers (the existing answers can still be seen). Over a long time the existing answers will be outdated. Henceforth closing such questions basically promotes bad quality content.

I also wonder if that kind of question is off-topic to which other site of Stack Exchange it should be migrated? If it's off-topic on Stack Overflow it should be on-topic elsewhere? Right?

I suggest to give some bagde for rewording and reopening good questions poorly worded. Maybe a "Baywatch" badge for saving good questions from drowning.

Comment: 'If it's off-topic on StackOverflow it should be on-topic elsewhere ? Right ?' - probably, yes.  Please search and let us know.

Comment: _"As I read it the question ask for a way to solve a specific programming problem, thus the question is specifically on topic"_ Except there are categories of these specific problems that are _still off-topic._ For example, problems where your question is _explicitly requesting an off-site resource._ Hence the close reason.

Comment: "_Henceforth closing such questions basically promotes bad quality content._"  Maybe in these select cases for old off-topic questions.  But overall, closing these kinds of unmaintainable recommendation questions keeps the rest of the site clean.  We don't need more of this kind of problem than we already have, so closure is absolutely appropriate.

Comment: *Just* rewriting a question doesn't fix the problem though. There's already a *ton* of very terrible answers on both of those questions that, if we're really going to go the extra mile to improve the question, need to be deleted because they provide no information other than a link to some external tool.

Comment: @animuson: yes. But the cleanup should merely be to delete (or at least downvote) the terrible answers. And beside that some answers are good.

Comment: @Martin James: I had some hope with "Software Suggestions", but it's useless for programmers. A "Programming Ressources" community would be a cool place to migrate such questions.

Comment: related: [Where can I ask about “finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)

Comment: @kriss If you think such a place would be useful, go ahead and create such a site.  Such is the beauty of the internet.

Comment: @Servy: there was such a place, you can find it easily using google search: it was called StackOverflow two years ago. But I agree that if it is dead now maybe some other site should replace it. Actually I'm much more involved with Quora than with SO. Quora has (many) issues and still lower quality content but the feeling there is much warmer than the current SO. Maybe more tidy but less useful and creative.

Comment: @kriss Those questions haven't been allowed on the site for like 7 years now.  They were by no means acceptable here 2 years ago.

Comment: "such" is too vague here. I agree I probably was a bit optimistic saying 2 years ago, 4 or 5 would probably be more accurate. But my feeling (is check statistics to check to confirm it) is that the current close brigade is more efficient and faster than in the past and sticking much more to the letter of the policy than the spirit. Wondering if the question is useful to professional programmers, or has actual answers seems not to be important for close brigade. Also reopen is very rare once a question has been closed. The more restrictive users have the upper hand.

Answer (score 5):

Stack Overflow is not here to answer all possible questions regarding programming. There are rules about what are on- and off-topic for very good reasons, which are explained in the corresponding topics in the help center. Additionally, questions off-topic on Stack Overflow are not necessarily on-topic anywhere else on the Stack Exchange network. Each site has its own definitions of what they deem on- and off-topic.

Those questions you've referenced were closed for the correct reason. We don't want a bunch of answers that might go stale in a few weeks when the next fad framework comes out.

Even if they did not specifically ask for libraries, they'd still be overly broad. They would be asking SO to implement an entire Web Socket server for them. SO is not a code-writing service, as much as some would like it to be.

The closed questions may eventually be deleted if enough people of high enough reputation vote for deletion, or they become eligible for auto-deletion, thus obviating any problems with closed questions getting out of date, which is actually why they were closed to begin with.

Comment: arbitrary restriction of SO perimeter may make it more tidy. But that's not what I'm seing today, on that level things didn't changed much. On the other hand overall site value is on a down slope because once valuable content  is now being rejected by policy. From my point of view (senior developper with 30 years of experience and lead contributor of an open source project) the site has now less value that it used to have, and I'm indeed spending more time now on other QA sites. Too much process kills process. Too bad.

Comment: And by the way implementing a "complete WebSocket server" (at least the skeleton) is typically a few dozains of lines. Not much harder than say asking how to read a text file line by line. But maybe it's also too much to ask SO community to write "a complete text file reader".

Answer (score 1):

After digging around I believe I've found out How should that kind of useful off topic questions should be managed. This does not involve reopening such questions.

I finally discovered there *IS* a place for such answers on stack overflow, just not on the Q&A part of the site.

Basically here is the place where I should have gone: [The WebSocket tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/websocket/info)

The drawback is that tag wikis are not exposed enough (site search does not search through them for instance, but only through Q&A content) and should probably be more actively maintained (for instance no link pointing to up to date Python implementation).

Maybe the "off-topic" close reason should not just state that these kind of questions are unwelcome but that they belong to tag wikis instead of Q&A would help.