# Is asking for "options" the same as asking for "recommendations"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I voted to close as *"asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource..."* and simply quoted the exact text of the close reason within a comment...

https://stackoverflow.com/q/38461842/594235

However, the OP is insisting that asking for "options" is very different than asking for "recommendations" (since *"the number of technical options is limited"*).  I disagree and am looking for additional opinions on this.

Comment: You are correct, and the OP is incorrect

Comment: Yikes...... even if this was closed the proper way and totally appropriately, I can sometimes understand new users who think we are ganging on posts :/

Comment: Though it would be better to consult the [close-voters chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) instead of asking a meta question.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Why is that better?

Comment: @Patrice Actually is backwards: if you put yourself in the middle of the highway it isn't weird that a bunch of cars hit you, but that doesn't mean that the cars are in the wrong, what the heck are you doing in the middle of the highway?

Comment: @Braiam Notice how I said "proper way and totally appropriately"? I also close voted. I'm not saying anything is wrong here. Just saying how I can understand the perception of new users. To use your own analogy... if you don't know anything about cars or highway and wake up in the middle of one, YES your perception will be that it's weird. The reality of the fact is something else.

Comment: @rene Because I don't like these kind of _drama questions_ on meta. Isn't that kind of question exactly what this chat room exists for? (I know I'm usually not participating)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ yes, that is correct and we have a protocol where we try to be as helpful as possible towards the OP with our comments, edits and close votes while still maintaining quality and on-topic-ness.   It is just that I don't often run into non-regulars that mention the room, specially in a context to avoid drama. So thanks for the suggestion and follow up.

Comment: The way to avoid silly arguments like this? Don't leave a comment. When the question is closed, the OP can read the reason in the help text.

Comment: "Too localized". Unfortunately, we don't have this close reason anymore. This, however, is a very special type, when a generally broad question was spiced up with restrictions criteria. Usually it's called "software solutions consulting", paid at 200$/hr and up.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, I did not leave a comment to start a silly argument. I left the comment to inform/educate the user, giving him a fair chance to edit/salvage the question *before* it gets closed.  Then I ignored his response to avoid a silly argument.

Comment: Obviously you didn't leave the comment to start a silly argument, that doesn't even make sense. But the question was unsalvageable, so the comment was pointless. What could the OP have done to prevent closure except ask a totally different question?

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot, the OP tried for something broad, but perhaps he had more specific issues.  I have no idea what was really in his mind, but I thought giving him a chance would be better than an anonymous close vote.

Comment: It looks to me like the distinction the OP is making is that an answer *endorsing* some technology would be making a "recommendation", but an answer that just *lists* technologies without stating opinions would be "giving options" and therefore OK. Obviously that's not how it works, but it's worth understanding where they went astray and what they got all in a huff about.

Comment: My 2-cents: If they ask for "options" in the design phase of their project then they are asking for off-topic recommendations. If they present code and ask for "optional" ways of accomplishing the code's result, then they ask a valid question. Your questioner appears to be in the design phase so your actions, IMHO, seem correct.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: "*Because I don't like these kind of drama questions on meta. Isn't that kind of question exactly what this chat room exists for?*" The problem is that the close voter's chat room is functionally invisible. So if you want to get the opinions of more than just the small cloister of people who go to that chat room, you have to do it on Meta.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is the same in this context, perhaps in different contexts it could depend, but anyone can clearly see that this question was looking for recommendations.

A link to a prominent library or tutorial solving their problem would have been the answer to that question, so despite the OP's claims against that the close reason was accurate.

I am not sure that simply restating the close reason in a comment was very helpful though, and it in a way invites a response which in general is going to be a critique on the semantic form of the reason as opposed to its functional form.

That said, there is nothing wrong with software recommendations, they just need to be on their appropriate site, which is 
[Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) .

See also: [Where can I ask about "finding a tool, library or favorite off-site resource?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/1026459)

Comment: I did not leave the comment to invite an argument. I left the comment to inform/educate the user, giving him a fair chance to edit/salvage the question before it gets closed.  Then I ignored his response to avoid any chance of argument.

Comment: @Sparky - I know that wasn't your intention, but users who have their questions downvoted/close voted tend to be overly defensive and so the likelihood of them being confrontational is higher.

Comment: Perhaps a custom message would have been taken a little better by the OP as opposed to the verbatim text of the recommendation close reason (which is also included in a banner).

Comment: IMO, my mistake was not putting quotation marks and "Quote SO FAQ:" in front of it.  That's the only way of ensuring my own opinion stays out of the comment.

Comment: Also, based on his comment, the OP's negative reaction was more likely sparked by a down-vote, which could have been left by anyone.