# Show warning when question body indicates a tool recommendation request

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions, recommendation-questions

I see numerous questions each day that contain clear indicators of off-site resource (usually a tool) recommendation requests.

Very often, those questions contain "What library" or similar wording.

If we can narrow it down to the most-used phrases (with a low false-positive rating), can we show a warning message to the user (or just new ones), not to post tool recommendation requests? Or will they just end up posting anyway?

Comment: I can see this having a lot of false positives, even with a list of commonly used phrases.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can identify such questions reliable enough that such an approach makes sense. It would be nice to try it out though. There should be enough data available in the data explorer to build a prototype and validate against it.

Comment: Well, that was my concern too. But I am not that smart, so I thought I'd ask you ;)

Comment: It it's only a warning, false positives are not a huge concern, IMO. But the vast majority will probably ignore the warning and continue posting anyway.

Comment: @yivi Depends on the severity.  A few false positives isn't a problem.  But if there a significant number of false positives, then it just adds too much noise that will get ignored.  I think this problem will fall closer to the latter.

Comment: I did a little test with the new ask question wizard. Question is about -> code. Tag -> Java. Title -> "Which library is recommended to parse XML?" . Result: a list of duplicate suggestions which are 90% closed. You know, there is more wrong than only the fact that the site just didn't care about me asking for a blatant library recommendation...

Comment: I fear all this will do is train people to use unclear phrasing to post the exact same resource requests. Like measuring productivity by the number of bugs fixed.

Comment: @CodyGray What if the warning included a link to a site which welcomed questions of these sort, such as Software Recommendations? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource

Comment: can't agree more with @ConspicuousCompiler. Getting a good answer to the question 'what tools are available to solve this problem ___' is often one of the most important questions in app architecture and development, despite the fact that SO doesn't allow them. We are here to help. Not say 'We don't serve you for those requests so you don't need to know just go to h*ll'. And in the end: the OP still needs a tool recommendation to get their job done.

Comment: I'd very much like to see this, as long as the warning is optional. OK, so some people will post their question anyway - and they might acquire more downvotes when readers see the behaviour as wilful. If it dissuades _some_ folks from posting, then that may save the community some work.

Comment: Not really a good idea, @Conspicuous. Experience has taught us that redirecting people with off-topic questions to other sites does not go over well. The other sites don't appreciate being a dumping ground for Stack Overflow's unwanted questions. Software Recommendations has *very* specific rules and requirements for their questions. Posting there without first reading their Help Center is bound to get you into trouble. Encouraging askers to take their questions to another site, just to have the question closed on that other site, is not an overall positive experience.

Comment: @FastAl "What tools are available for X" is a question that Google can solve for you. We simply don't need to duplicate that work on SO.

Comment: @IanKemp So is every other question asked on SO. But SO does Q&A better and when recommendations were more allowed, SO could answer those questions better too. Yes, it's harder to manage. But whomever has pity for those who shy away from profitable things just because they are hard?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think it could be nice to have a Banner appear with like:

> Over 50% of the similar sounding Questions are closed, are you sure this is in Scope.

The probably best solution with the least false positives would be to add a new Type: "I need to find a Book/Guide/Library" like we have with "I need a software recommendation".

[image: Suggestion]

For that we should consider if the "hardware/software" recommendations options worked and actually reduced the off-topic questions and so make this option possible and useful.

Comment: I would go for option #2. And add "tutorial".