# Rules for voting close when OP is looking for suggestions

Tags: discussion, questions, specific-question, scope, vote-to-close

How do you word a question that is asking for possible solutions or tools so that it is not immediately closed by observant curators?

My question ([How to verify external symbols in an .h file to the .c file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60504654/how-to-verify-external-symbols-in-an-h-file-to-the-c-file)) was closed in about 1 minute on the reason that it asked for recommendations. It did not.

How can we support the development community if all questions about what tools there are to solve a problem, is closed as "asking for recommendation". Isn't the question "is there such a tool" answerable with facts?

I propose a change in the interpretation, and culture in SO, so that only questions containing words like "best", "better", "recommended" and so on are possible to close referring to "no recommendations".

Comment: Not sure if it is needed but wouldn't it also need to state which C compiler you use? Just in case gcc does come with such an option but msvc doesn't.

Comment: 'yes there is such a tool'. How helpful is this, *without* the tool recommendation? Be honest with yourself, you want to know the tool

Comment: [“…it is still possible to get a library recommendation on Stack Overflow. But by focusing on the library, you are approaching the situation completely backwards. Stack Overflow is not about "finding things", it is about solving problems. So your question should focus on your problem. When you are looking for a library, more often than not, you have a specific problem you trying to solve. Ask about **that** problem…”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/351562)

Comment: [“I believe you may be misunderstanding the purpose of the close reason. … The issue is questions explicitly asking for *something* (tool, library, book, etc) turn into popularity contests as well as magnets for spam and other low quality answers. This issue is somewhat mitigated when the question doesn't actually ask for a tool. …”](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605)

Answer (score 16):

> Is there some tool or script that can help [...]

That's asking for recommendations for external tools or resources. That you do not expect the answers to be written like *"This is the the best tool for this task, which I recommend"*, does not make it less of a recommendation request.

> **To those who voted to closed this**: I'm not looking for recommendations, only a list of possible solutions. Possible solutions are facts, right?!? Gaaah!

The "list of possible solutions" is a list of "recommended solutions". You want a list of external resources or tools.

I'm afraid the site is ill suited for this kind of question, and I believe it was correctly closed.

The fact that you are not asking for "the best tool" for this purpose does not make a difference.

The question could be rewritten to ask "how to perform this task", instead of "are there tools or scripts to perform this task", in which case it would be sensibly better. If it would be worth reopening the question or not in that case I leave up to subject matter experts.

<sub>**Note: Since I posted this rene offered an edit on your original question which might be enough to reopen it. There is already a reopen vote as I write.**</sub>

Comment: I gave that question an edit, invalidating some of your points, sorry about that.

Comment: @rene I like that edit. I wanted to write yivi that I agree with him, but I also think that this question can be resurrected by removing those lines to make it on-topic. It also don't look too broad for me.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @rene, I'll take a look. I don't think it would invalidate my points, since I addressed the revision the OP was asking about. Still, I also added a bit about the possibility of editing the question into shape. Maybe your edit took the question in that direction.

Comment: @rene Indeed, your edit seems to be in line with my closing paragraph. So I guess it's all good in the end.

Comment: Thank you for addressing this, but I don't agree that "how to perform this task" as opposed to "are there tools or scripts to perform this task" is "sensibly better". To me it is just a play with words. If those nuances in wording are required to get past the "guards of close voting" I think we have a worse problem than questions that might spark some discussions (which questions are actually answerable with "facts"?)

Comment: Is there another StackExchange that doesn't have this culture of closing anything that can be seen as "recommendations" where I could put this question and not getting it closed? Software Engineering perhaps?

Comment: [Software Recs](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) maybe?

Answer (score -1):

The message from the vote-to-close window says "recommendations", but the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) expands on this (emphasis mine):

> Questions asking us to recommend **or find** a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

That is, even if the question is only asking for external resources without an expression of opinion, the question is still off-topic because it would *"tend to attract opinionated answers"* even if opinions are not explicitly solicited.

So you can ask questions which could be answered by "tool X solves your problem"; but the question should be about the problem, not your need for a tool to solve it.

Comment: Again, I think this is just splitting hairs. There is as much risk of opinionated answers to "how can I solve X?" as there is to "is there a tool to solve X?". I strongly feel that this interpretation severely limits what questions are on-topic for  "professional and enthusiast programmers". Few questions in the domain of programming will be hard facts.

Comment: If SO *really* want to have "detailed answers to every question about programming" there has to be some lenience with the interpretation of what is likely to attract opinionated answers and spam, instead of a litteral interpretation of the rules. (the quotes are from the main page for SO, https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: I'm not saying we should encourage writing questions that are focused on the problem. But just closing anything that is not, is not a good way to great citizens of the community.

Comment: There is lenience about what is interpreted as opinion; see under "some subjective questions are allowed" [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), and [this SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: Thanks, those pointers actually say much of what I mean. So I'll just have to write off this occurance to folks following the letter and not the actual intent. Anyways the question got re-opened again, so ...