# Where can I ask programming related questions about if there is a tool for doing task X?

Tags: support

I asked a question on stackoverflow about if there is a tool which is able to detect conflicts in two CSS files, but the question was closed as off-topic with the following reason:

**We don’t allow questions seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more.**

Is there a place on this site where I can ask such questions to the community or do I need to ask it on another website?

Comment: The only place in this network it *might* be on topic is [softwarerecs.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I ask about "finding a tool, library, or favorite off-site resource?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251134/where-can-i-ask-about-finding-a-tool-library-or-favorite-off-site-resource)

Comment: Reddit has a number of good programming forums.  I often suggest moving questions to the appropriate reddit group when the question is valid but still violates stackoverflow's policies.  Had some excellent discussions as a result.

Answer (score 9):

You can't and you shouldn't.

Just leave out the tool.

> *How can I accomplish task X*

is fine, as long as X is programming related and reasonably scoped (X is scoped perfectly fine here, it is after all a single letter, not the whole freaking alphabet. Could have been worse, it could have been a word, or even a word with a meaning) .

You might need to elaborate on X a bit. If doing one X is easy but having to do X 100 times is cumbersome or if you can't find where you have to do X. That context helps in establishing the value of knowing the answer to task X.

Answers to questions about task X will be one of:

- It can't be done
- You need to do Y so you don't need X
- The steps to accomplish task X
- A tool that solves task X
- A function of an IDE that does task X

If you're 100% sure you're looking for a software tool and a software tool only and have a finite set of requirements check out the [question guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) of [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: "'How can I accomplish task X' is fine, as long as X is programming related." I would expect such question to get closed as "needs more focus".

Comment: @TadeuszKopec _How to_ Q's are on topic.  There's a line between that and _here's my requirements. Will someone do this for me (often not explicitly stated but implied)_

Comment: @TadeuszKopec Aye, or downvoted for a lack of research. This answer is what I consider a "*should* be good advice" in a perfect world where people understand and reasonably apply the written rules rather than follow them to the letter, but I'm pretty sure it is going to lead to some unpleasant experiences for people.

Comment: Example of this happening, in my opinion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63675840/find-out-age-of-page-using-javascript-and-reload-if-too-old . Perfectly valid "how can I" question, but it's closed as needs more focus and is being downvoted.

Comment: @Gimby you can re-open vote it, you have the privilege